# Cordova iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ide, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to create a Cordova app for learning purposes to deploy to my iPhone 5 for personal testing. 
For the life of me however I can't seem to understand what I have to do. I have Xcode installed as all the tutorials have mentioned. How do I create a provisioning profile (with a free developer account)? How do I sign my device? 
Nothing I've found online seems to explain in clearly, or for beginners such as myself.

Also, is there a way to create all of this but *not* use Xcode as my IDE for developing my app?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use XCode to develop your Cordova app, as the app is just CSS, JavaScript, and HTML. I like to use WebStorm, but you can use whatever suits you. However, in order to deploy your app to a device, you do need XCode. [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device/33928777#33928777) to an answer for a similar question. This is in regards to XCode 7 and I'm not sure what version you have, or if this still holds for XCode 8.

You only deploy after you do a build for iOS with Cordova, by running `$ cordova build`. [Here is a link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/index.html) to Cordova's docs.