# How can I test my iphone application on iPhone device before submittimg it to Apple Store?

Tags: iphone, testing

How can I test my iphone application on iPhone device before submittimg it to Apple Store?

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to join the [iPhone Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/). This will give you a digital certificate that you can use to sign your application and allow it to both run on your own iPhone and submit it to the App Store. The docs are available when you sign up and are generally pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iPhone emulator built into the latest XCode

You can attach an iPhone or iPod touch to your Mac and XCode will run your app directly on the device, with debugging support.