# iPhone Error while building application for Device

Tags: iphone, code-signing

I want to deploy an application to the iPhone which I previously tested on Simulator. I am following the jailbreak way but [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store#37522)

but when I change the setting to Project, Set Active SDK, Device, I get the CodeSign Error as follows: Code Signing Identity 'iPhone Developer' does not match any code-signing certificate in your keychain. Once added to the keychain, touch a file or clean the project to continue.

Any ideas how can I go about this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a code signing certificate using Keychain Access.

Here's a tutorial: [Bypass Code Signature & Published Your Application on Cydia](http://adeem.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/bypass-code-signature-published-your-application-on-cydia/)