# iOS develop and provision private apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, jailbreak

I want to develop some small apps for personal use. I don't want to market them, nor I want anyone other but me to have them. As a developer, I want to be able to put some minor utility app I'd like to have on my own smartphone (an iPhone, of course).

As I'm not going to develop anything commercial in the near future, I'm not going to subscribe the developer program. Is it possible to develop personal apps without subscribing to Apple's program? Would jailbreak help? Am I going to miss any possibility in the development (ability to subscribe to servers, message, use the maps...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a number of threads of this.. they all use ldid and are normally jailbroken

[How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)

[Attempting to deploy my app on my jailbroken iphone, but the app closes immediately!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285980/attempting-to-deploy-my-app-on-my-jailbroken-iphone-but-the-app-closes-immediat)