# Problem when deploy to real device: The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

How to solve this problem, please help:
[image]

More detail, please view this image: [detail image](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_ASRRmy9UkLk/S2LVK7hSzFI/AAAAAAAAAII/WZfVRFOzpz4/s640/Screen%20shot%202010-01-29%20at%207.29.04%20PM.png)

Answer (score 10):

It appears that your certificate has expired, assuming your clock is correctly set on your machine. Open the keychain access application and view the details of the certificate you generated on the developer portal. If the certificate is expired, then you need to create a new one from the portal, download and install it on your machine. Then, you will need to modify in your project settings the identity signing the code to reflect your new certificate.

Comment: I have remove the expired certificates from the keychain. Now it is working fine

Answer (score 7):

I tried a few things, including restarting (both the iPhone, and Xcode), but here's a few things that you can do if you're having this problem:

- Go to Keychain Access, find your developer profile, delete them and re download it from Developer Member Centre.
- In Xcode, go to Preferences -> Accounts and remove your Apple ID, and add it back.
- In my case, doing the above will trigger Xcode to create me a new certificate. I just did that and it worked.

Comment: Removing the account and adding it back worked for me