# How to use camera of iPhone using web technologies

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an iPhone Web App use the Camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647892/can-an-iphone-web-app-use-the-camera)

I developed an application using web technologies such as HTML,JavaScript,CSS. I am web camera to capture the images

I want this application compatible for mobiles and should launch the iphone camera.

How to do?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647892/can-an-iphone-web-app-use-the-camera

Answer (score 0):

i think this is not possible.because ready made API's are provided for this.but in ios5 there are some API which provide such things to you........