# private application for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store, appstore-approval, iphone-developer-program

one of my client want an private application for iPhone. actually what my client need is, they want the application only for their company employees they are not interested to go for the app store for this. their company has 100+ employees. is it possible to sale the application without the app store. if its give me the solution.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the enterprise support for iPhone development. I believe that will let you do what you want.

Check out [Apple - Support iPhone - Enterprise](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go through Apple, you don't have to.  Contrary to Apple's exhortations, this is perfectly [legal](http://www.copyright.gov/1201/).  See [iPhone App Minus App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store/37522#37522) for discussion of the technical details.