# Deploy an iphone app from xcode to iphone

Tags: iphone

I am doing a school project and I am required to deploy an iphone app to my phone. I have some really noob questions to ask. I have tried to read some solutions from this website but I dont understand! like from these questions: [iPhone app minus app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store#37522) and [How can I deploy an iphone application from xcode to real iPhone device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device).

Can anyone here give me an easier way to understand please?

Comment: What exactly are you not understanding? If you read the first link you posted again, all the information is there.

Answer (score 34):

Easy:

- [Sign up for an iOS Developer account](http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/). This includes signing up for an Apple ID, enrolling as an Apple developer, then opting that dev account into the Developer Program. That link walks you through the process.
- Hook up your device to your machine and look at it in the Xcode organizer (Window > Organizer).
- Tell Xcode your want to use it for development.

I believe Xcode will now help you out more than it used to. If it doesn't, then Apple has step-by-step instructions. In short, you need to:

- Use Keychain Access to generate a CSR (certificate signing request)
- Submit that to Apple via the dev portal
- Download the resulting development signing certificate and install it along with Apple's intermediate certificate in your keychain by double-clicking on the files.
- You then need to create a provisioning profile.
- Add your device ID to it.
- Download it and stick it on your device, e.g., by dragging it to your device in iTunes.

Then, you can build and run your app on the device. It's a pain to explain, but pretty easy to feel your way through once you get started.

Answer (score 9):

My fuller answer with pictures is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33928777/3681880).

With Xcode 7 for an iOS 9 target device there is now free provisioning. You don't have to sign up for the Apple Developer Program in order to test an app on a real device.

Summary from the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27):

> If you don’t join the Apple Developer Program, you can still build and
>   run your app on your devices using *free provisioning*....
>
> 1. In Xcode, add your Apple ID to Accounts preferences
> 2. In the project navigator, select the project and your target to display the project editor.
> 3. Click General and choose your name from the Team pop-up menu.
> 4. Connect the device to your Mac and choose your device from the Scheme toolbar menu.
> 5. Below the Team pop-up menu, click Fix Issue.
> 6. Click the Run button.

When you run your app on a device, you will also have to trust the developer first. On your device go to **Settings > General > Profile > developer account name > Trust**.

Related articles:

- [Xcode 7 allows anyone to download, build and ‘sideload’ iOS apps for free](http://9to5mac.com/2015/06/10/xcode-7-allows-anyone-to-download-build-and-sideload-ios-apps-for-free/)
- [iOS Untrusted Developer error when testing app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206143/ios-untrusted-developer-error-when-testing-app)
- [iOS9 Untrusted Enterprise Developer with no option to trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust)

Answer (score 3):

This SO question here gives detailed steps of how to do what Jeremy suggests.

[How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)

Take note that /Developer was moved to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer in Xcode 4.3.

And, this SO question says what to do if you get an [sed: RE error : Illegal byte sequence].

[RE error: illegal byte sequence on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/sed-re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x)

But in XCode-5.1/MacOS-10.9, this still didn't work - I lost the devices tab in XCode-Organizer after editing the plist file!