# "invalid command code ." error from sed after running find and sed on Mavericks

Tags: command-line, sed, find, osx-mavericks

I run the following command to find and replace an old web address to a new one.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i \
's/http:\/\/www\.oldwebaddress\.com\/techblog/https:\/\/github\.com\/myname/g'
```

However I get the following error.

```
sed: 1: "./.DS_Store": invalid command code .
```

I tried this one after reading some of Stack Overflow posts but didn't work either.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" \
's/http:\/\/www\.oldwebaddress\.com\/techblog/https:\/\/github\.com\/myname/g'

sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

The `sed` on Mac OS X accepts the `-i` option but requires an argument, the suffix to use for the backup files.  It is not optional as it is with GNU `sed`.  So, the `sed` script tries to use your `s///` command as the suffix, and then the first file name didn't happen to be a valid `sed` command.

For the second attempt, with `-i ""`, it is not quite so clear what's up.  I assume there's either a backslash after the `""` or the whole lot is really on one line, so that it is syntactically correct.

It is simpler to use some character other than `/` as the separator when editing path names.  Often, `%` works:

```
-e 's%http://www\.oldwebaddress\.com/techblog%https://github\.com/myname%g'
```

but you can use any character; <kbd>Control-A</kbd> or <kbd>Control-G</kbd> are quite effective too and even more unlikely to appear in a URL than `%`.

It is not clear to me, though, why you're getting the RE error (invalid byte sequence). Copying and pasting from the question doesn't show a problem, and the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/sed-re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x) referenced suggests `LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C` but I'm not running into problems with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and nothing set for `LC_CTYPE`.

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/sed-re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x) help?

Also if you will just do `-print` instead of `-print0` then you can replace `xargs -0` with just `xargs`.

You might also consider using `perl` instead of BSD `sed`.

```
find . -type f -print | xargs perl -pi.bak -e 's/http\:\/\/www\.oldwebaddress\.com\/techblog/https\:\/\/github\.com\/myname/g'
```

Above should do the replacements and save all files backups adding `.bak` at the end of filenames. Use `perl -pi -e` if you don't want backups to be created.

Comment: `-print0`/`xargs -0` is useful in cases where you care about filenames with newlines :)