# Delete a string from all files in a directory

Tags: bash, sed

I am looking for a tool/command to delete string "http://" from all files within a directory. I am using the following command on my MacOS but am not able to accomplish the task.

```
grep -lr --exclude-dir=".git" -e "http://" . | xargs sed -i "" "s/"http:\/\/"//g"
```

I get the following error on command line:

sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the related question on the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/sed-re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x

Comment: That seems to be solution for Linux. I am asking for solution in MacOS. Also, I am not sure if the command is totally correct.

Comment: Did you try `find . -type f -exec sed -i "" 's|http://||g' {} \;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have double quotes within a double quoted string. Try

```
grep ... | xargs sed -i "" 's@"http://"@@g'
```

Using different delimiters for `s///` to avoid the leaning toothpick syndrome.