# Replace the occurrences in file name, folder name and file content

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have folders and files with the following structure and some of the files contains the string `ModuleName`.

```
ModuleName
├── Application\ Logic
│   └── Interactor
│       ├── ModuleNameInteractor.swift
│       └── ModuleNameInteractorIO.swift
├── Module\ Interface
│   └── IModuleNameModule.swift
└── User\ Interface
    ├── Presenter
    │   └── ModuleNamePresenter.swift
    ├── View
    │   ├── IModuleNameView.swift
    │   └── ModuleNameViewController.swift
    └── Wireframe
        └── ModuleNameWireframe.swift
```

I want to replace all the occurrences of `ModuleName` in folder name, file name and file content by another name (let's say `TestModule`) with a Linux or a python script.

I tried with the `find` command but renaming the folders provoque `No such file or directory` for the subfolders / subfiles.

Comment: Can you say little bit more about `"I want to replace  all the occurrences of ModuleName in ... file content"`

Comment: For example, the file `ModuleNameInteractor.swift` contain the following code `class ModuleNameInteractor : ModuleNameInteractorInput` and after executing the script, I want to get `class TestModuleInteractor : TestModuleInteractorInput`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `sed -i` (in-place replace) for the content replacements, and a `find|while read` loop for the renames.

Here's the BSD sed (standard on Macs) version:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -e s/ModuleName/TestModule/g -i '' '{}' ';'
find . -depth -name '*ModuleName*' -print0|while IFS= read -rd '' f; do mv -i "$f" "$(echo "$f"|sed -E 's/(.*)ModuleName/\1TestModule/')"; done
```

And here's GNU sed:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -e s/ModuleName/TestModule/g -i '{}' ';'
find . -depth -name '*ModuleName*' -print0|while IFS= read -rd '' f; do mv -i "$f" "$(echo "$f"|sed -r 's/(.*)ModuleName/\1TestModule/')"; done
```

The extra details in the `while read` are to correctly handle arbitrary filenames -- names with spaces and other odd characters. Some quick testing suggests that zsh `read` can now handle null-terminated strings properly; if you have issues, try running it in bash instead.

Comment: I have modified the commands to work in mac (`find . -type f -name '*ModuleName*' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0/ModuleName/Test}"' '{}' \;
find . -name '*ModuleName*' -print0|while IFS= read -rd '' f; do mv -i "$f" "${f//ModuleName/Test}"; done`) but I got errors :http://0bin.net/paste/Fp4Vo46LzuXC5Q0f#XSc1UBdGOwnJ1YpgdCmafXDe-XqLC67MBd+RA+B168m (sed replace the first occurrence in the path).

Comment: I've edited it to give what I hope is a correct Mac version, and also to fix a bug--my original rename logic failed to account for the fact that the directory got renamed first, so after the first mv, the files were no longer reachable by their original path. The fix is to replace them from the bottom up (`find -depth`), changing only the *last* occurrence of `ModuleName` in each path each time.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you ! On OSX I have this error message `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence` but the solution can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I assume the error is in the first statement, the `sed -i`? Do you know what character encoding the files you're editing are in?

Answer (score 0):

After trying to fight with the terminal, I found out that the Massreplaceit app available for free [here](http://www.hexmonkeysoftware.com) can handle this problem very easily

PS : I am not working there !