# Recursive find and replace Unix path

Tags: sed, substitution

I am trying to recursively find and replace all instances of `root` with `usr/local`.

I know that this command:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/apple/orange/g' {} \;
```

works when trying to replace a string without "/" with another, but how do I do this to include "/" in the replaced string?

Comment: escape that thing: `'s/root/user\/local/g'`

Comment: @JNevill when i tried this i get:    sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

Comment: Are you on a [mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x)?

Comment: Yes. I am on a mac @JNevill

Comment: Then it may be a locale type of issue. Try: `find ./ -type f -exec LC_ALL=C sed -i -e 's/root/user\/local/g' {} \;`

Comment: This gives me find: LC_ALL=C: No such file or directory @JNevill

Comment: Fine then. Stick that thing before the `find` if it's going to be picky like that: `LC_ALL=C  find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/root/user\/local/g' {} \;` Not 100% if that will work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: This works, but gives me 2 versions of the file, one with a -e after it (with the previous changes), and one without -e which has the updated version. How do I make the -e version removed? @JNevill thank you for your help sorry for the silly questions

Comment: Honestly... I have no idea on that one. Perhaps drop that oddball `-e` flag on your sed command. Total 100% guess on that one though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a `/` in the replacement it can either be escaped with a `\`,
or the `s` command can use a different delimiter:

```
sed 's|root|usr/local|g' ...
```

Additionally the (non-standard) `-i` option requires an argument in FreeBSD `sed(1)` and, by extension, macOS (OS X) `sed(1)`.  In this case giving a zero-length argument (`-i ''`) will have the same effect as having no argument would for GNU `sed(1)`.

However the [man-page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed) warns against that usage:

> It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.

Also, if the extention is not in its own argument then the syntaxes are compatible:

```
sed -i.bak 's|root|usr/local|g' ...
```