# sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence and locale settings

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I want to replace words in files recursively. This command:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/myOldTag/myNewTag/g' {} \;
```

does the job but I get a number of error messages:

```
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

My locale settings:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I tried also:

```
LANG=sl $$ find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/myOldTag/myNewTag/g' {} \;
```

but without success, error messages are the same.

Comment: Have you tried `LC_ALL=C sed ....`?

Comment: I tried, it works, thank you.

Comment: To be quite precise, my initial command did not work, this one did the job: `LC_ALL=C  find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/myOldTag/myNewTag/g' {} \;`

Comment: A very detailed explanation and discussion of alternatives can be found here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x`