# sed: Replace double quote won't work in Terminal

Tags: bash, sed

I have csv files with newlines within fields. Now I would like to remove them without removing the newline at the end of the row.

The end of the rows have a closing double quote like so:

`...;"25.33"\n`

So in order to remove the newlines within the fields I try to remove every newline that is not preceded by a double quote. The regular expression for that would be: `[^"]\n`

And in `sed`:

`sed -i -E "s/[^"]\n/ /g" *.csv`   # a newline not following a double quote

I get a complaint in bash:

```
➜ sed -i -E "s/[^"]\n/ /g" *.csv
dquote>
```

Obviously I have to escape the quote within the brackets:

`sed -i -E "s/[^\"]\n/ /g" *.csv`

But that won't work either:

```
➜  csv_working_copy1 sed -i -E "s/[^\"]\n/ /g" *.csv
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

What am I missing?

---

## Example

This is an example row

```
"2019-03-17";"Comment \n
with newline within it";"23.88"\n
```

I would like to have this output

```
"2019-03-17";"Comment with newline within it";"23.88"\n
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed '/ $/{:a;N;s/\n//;/ $/{ba}}' file`?

Comment: @Ugur, Could you please add more sample lines, can there be more than 2 lines which needed to be in single line? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the single quote for the outermost double quote:

```
sed -i -E 's/[^"]\n/ /g' *.csv
```

Comment: Tried that as well, but I get the same error: `➜  sed -i -E 's/[^\"]\n/ /g' *.csv
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence` Maybe I need to add that I use a Mac + iTerm?

Comment: Don't escape the " with \", please see my example.

Comment: I am sorry. You are right. But still the same error :(  `sed -i -E 's/[^"]\n/ /g' *.csv
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`

Comment: Obviously the error resulted from the content of the file. It's a Mac specific error. I should have googled "sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence". This would have led me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x

Comment: No need of -i here, the command do nothing. sed never see \n !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk that should handle it:

```
$ awk -v RS="^$" '{            # read the whole file in at the beginning
    for(i=1;i<=length;i++) {   # iterate file char at a time
        c=substr($0,i,1)       # read char
        if(c=="\"")            # if its a quote
            f=!f               # ... flag up, of down if already up
        if(c=="\n" && f)       # if its newline and flag is up ie. within quotes
            c=""               # replace newline with null
        printf "%s",c          # print char
    }
}' file
```

Output with the sample:

```
"2019-03-17";"Comment \nwith newline within it";"23.88"\n
```

More records:

```
$ awk ... file file file
"2019-03-17";"Comment \nwith newline within it";"23.88"\n
"2019-03-17";"Comment \nwith newline within it";"23.88"\n
"2019-03-17";"Comment \nwith newline within it";"23.88"\n
```

It won't tolerate any quote problems, naturally.

**Update**: Another shorter solution:

```
$ awk '{if((c+=gsub(/"/,"&"))%2==0)print;else printf "%s",$0}' file
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '{
    if((c+=gsub(/"/,"&"))%2==0)  # keep count of quotes, if count is even:
        print                    # print with newline
    else                         # else
        printf "%s",$0           # omit newline
}'
```

Comment: James, thank you very much. That is a very good solution. But I was wondering how I could do it with `sed`

Comment: I would assume that the accepted answer is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Another awk :

```
awk '!($0~"\"$"){a=a$0;next}{$0=a $0;a=""}1' infile
```