# Bash 'cut' command for Mac

Tags: bash, macos, cut

I want to cut everything with a delimiter ":" The input file is in the following format:

```
data1:data2
data11:data22
...
```

I have a linux command

```
cat merged.txt | cut -f1 -d ":" > output.txt
```

On mac terminal it gives an error:

```
cut: stdin: Illegal byte sequence
```

what is the correct way to do it on a mac terminal?

Comment: What's the output of `file merged.txt`?

Comment: second part after colon

Comment: This would appear to be an issue with your input file, not `cut` itself.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x

Comment: No, I meant what is the output of the command `file` applied to `merged.txt`. It'll tell you what your system thinks that file is (ASCII or not, carriage returns etc.)

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite understand the question. The merged.txt file has strings detached with colon. I need to cut everything before the colon and the colon itself and output everything after it in a new file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RE error: illegal byte sequence on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input file (merged.txt) probably contains bytes/byte sequences that are not valid in your current locale. For example, your locale might specify UTF-8 character encoding, but the file be in some other encoding and cannot be parsed as valid UTF-8. If this is the problem, you can work around it by telling `tr` to assume the "C" locale, which basically tells it to process the input as a stream of bytes without paying attention to encoding.

BTW, `cat file |` is what's commonly referred to as a Useless Use of Cat (UUOC) -- you can just use a standard input redirect `< file` instead, which cleaner and more efficient. Thus, my version of your command would be:

```
LC_ALL=C cut -f1 -d ":" < merged.txt > output.txt
```

Note that since the `LC_ALL=C` assignment is a prefix to the `tr` command, it only applies to that one command and won't mess up other operations that *should* assume UTF-8 (or whatever your normal locale is).

Answer (score 0):

Your cut command works for me on my Mac, you can try awk for the same result

```
awk -F: '{print $1}' merged.txt

data1
data11
```