# Find and replace string in file (macOS bash script)?

Tags: bash, macos, awk, sed, terminal

I have a log file, like this:

**`compile.log`**

```
C:\Program Files\File.ext(25,10) : error <ERROR_CODE>: <ERROR_MESSAGE>
C:\Program Files\File.ext(36,13) : error <ERROR_CODE>: <ERROR_MESSAGE>
C:\Program Files\File.ext(41,51) : warning <WARNING>: <WARNING>
C:\Program Files\File.ext(64,55) : error <ERROR_CODE>: <ERROR_MESSAGE>
 : information: result 3 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

And want it like this:

**`compile.log`**

```
/Users/user/Library/Folders/Program Files/File.ext(25,10) : error <ERROR_CODE>: <ERROR_MESSAGE>
/Users/user/Library/Folders/Program Files/File.ext(36,13) : error <ERROR_CODE>: <ERROR_MESSAGE>
/Users/user/Library/Folders/Program Files/File.ext(41,51) : warning <WARNING>: <WARNING>
/Users/user/Library/Folders/Program Files/File.ext(64,55) : error <ERROR_CODE>: <ERROR_MESSAGE>
 : information: result 3 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

Tried numerous `sed` and `awk` alternatives with various error messages.
 Could someone show me a working (macOS 10.14.1) solution?

---

UPDATE: Everything works as expected, after I **converted `compile.log` to UTF-8**. Seemingly the windows environment created the log `utf-16le` encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed 's/C:\\Program Files\\File.ext/\/Users\/user\/Library\/Folders\/Program Files\/File.ext/g' compile.log > compile-replaced.log`

Comment: Thanks! However, it actually shows an empty `compile-replaced.log`. It says: `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`

Comment: use `s\@...@...@` form for search targets that include `/` chars (you may or may not need the leading `\` char. Good luck.

Comment: Now it is either a `sed: 1: "s\@C:\\Program Files@\/ ...": substitute pattern can not be delimited by newline or backslash` or the `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence` without the leading \.

Comment: @Geri Maybe you should get more info here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x]

Comment: Thanks, I did get the info there (been trial and erroring for hours now), but the strings did not get replaced (`compile-replaced.log` have the same content as the original).

Comment: Thanks, it was an encoding issue, nothing in particular with `sed`. Nevertheless, the answer works just fine.

Comment: When working with directory paths it's better to just choose some other delimiter than `/` for the sed command so you don't need to escape all the `/`s in the path, e.g.:  `s:/abc/def:/ghi:` instead of `s/\/abc\/def/\/f\ghi/'`

Comment: @Geri : Check your `LANG` variable, whether it matches the encoding for the file.