# Best way to pull repeated table data from a pcap http file (could awk handle the disruptive breaks)?

Tags: awk, separator

I am collecting data readings from my PV system. The web client will graph one day of data - I want to collect a whole year or two in one file for patterns etc.
So far I capture lines into a cap file with Wireshark and just filter the data I want with headers and a few retransmitted packet.
The data of interest is being sent to a js app but I want to lift out the data which repeats in each packet as **date time=watts,** see sample below...

I was hoping to use AWK to parse the data into an array keyed by date and time, then print it back out to a file. This gets rid of duplicates in retransmitted packets and sorts the data. I ideally I'd also remove unwanted decimal data in the watts field too.

This sample was passed through strings to remove binary data in the cap. Can awk handle that better?
There are regular packet breaks that interrupt the fields at any place, in this sample with the year 2018 with the 20 being at the end of a packet and the 18 in the start of the next. The inter-line text is not consistent though there might be something more consistent in the binary file. 
So the rule needs to be:

- ignore until `{"1":"{`
- parse for 4n-2n-2n space 2n:2n space real_nb comma (ignoring any other line breaks or chars)
- stop collecting at `}","0":"2018-01-01"}` NB the end dates vary!

Here are 2 sample blocks. The first shows strings around a table block that has been shortened to just a few times from that day.
The second block is just the full table data from a day without the context.

(I added a line break for visual separation. Note break within the 76.549995 which would be better rounded as 77)

```
Path=/
/[CB
$e/N
{"1":"{2018-01-08 08:50=4.5, 2018-01-08 08:55=9.5, 2018-01-08 11:30=76
/[CB
$e/QM
.549995, 2018-01-08 11:35=73.9, 2018-01-08 11:40=65.93333, 2018-01-08 15:30=2.25, 2018-01-08 15:40=0.0}","0":"2018-01-08"}
/[CB
$e/Vq
XT2P

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"1":"{2018-01-01 08:15=9.5, 2018-01-01 08:20=22.0, 2018-01-01 08:25=29.4, 2018-01-01 08:30=30.150002, 2018-01-01 08:35=35.3, 2018-01-01 08:40=42.0, 2018-01-01 08:45=77.5, 2018-01-01 08:50=62.6, 2018-01-01 08:55=62.6, 2018-01-01 09:00=75.4, 2018-01-01 09:05=61.199997, 2018-01-01 09:10=57.85, 2018-01-01 09:15=45.7, 2018-01-01 09:20=44.266666, 2018-01-01 09:25=47.2, 2018-01-01 09:30=46.8, 2018-01-01 09:35=53.2, 2018-01-01 09:40=58.2, 2018-01-01 09:45=55.600002, 2018-01-01 09:50=56.733337, 2018-01-01 09:55=62.0, 2018-01-01 10:00=66.3, 2018-01-01 10:05=62.466663, 2018-01-01 10:10=62.699997, 2018-01-01 10:15=70.3, 2018-01-01 10:20=87.1, 2018-01-01 10:25=88.24999, 2018-01-01 10:30=102.5, 2018-01-01 10:35=95.46667, 2018-01-01 10:40=100.73334, 2018-01-01 10:45=100.700005, 2018-01-01 10:50=102.06667, 2018-01-01 10:55=116.4, 20
/[CB
X7BP
18-01-01 11:00=126.7, 2018-01-01 11:05=125.166664, 2018-01-01 11:10=128.26666, 2018-01-01 11:15=125.43333, 2018-01-01 11:20=119.666664, 2018-01-01 11:25=116.649994, 2018-01-01 11:30=94.700005, 2018-01-01 11:35=101.7, 2018-01-01 11:40=95.13333, 2018-01-01 11:45=98.76666, 2018-01-01 11:50=98.466675, 2018-01-01 11:55=92.43334, 2018-01-01 12:00=85.96667, 2018-01-01 12:05=77.833336, 2018-01-01 12:10=75.95, 2018-01-01 12:15=67.75, 2018-01-01 12:20=57.699997, 2018-01-01 12:25=74.2, 2018-01-01 12:30=87.1, 2018-01-01 12:35=77.6, 2018-01-01 12:40=74.1, 2018-01-01 12:45=63.36667, 2018-01-01 12:50=59.300003, 2018-01-01 12:55=76.9, 2018-01-01 13:00=66.6, 2018-01-01 13:05=203.4, 2018-01-01 13:10=203.45, 2018-01-01 13:15=203.45, 2018-01-01 13:20=157.3, 2018-01-01 13:25=101.333336, 2018-01-01 13:30=96.45, 2018-01-01 13:35=81.3, 2018-01-01 13:40=93.7, 2018-01-01 13:45=127.9, 2018-01-01 13:50=176.1, 2018-01-01 13:55=152.0, 2018-01-01 14:00=169.6, 2018-01-01 14:05=203.2, 2018-01-01 14:10=257.5, 2018-01-01 14:15=261.30002, 2018-01-01 14:20=261.3, 2018-01-01 14:25=218.13335, 2018-01-01 14:30=385.5, 2018-01-01 14:35=287.5, 2018-01-01 14:40=248.35002, 2018-01-01 14:45=98.2, 2018-01-01 14:50=136.2, 2018-01-01 14:55=160.0, 2018-01-01 15:00=148.1
/[CB
X7BP
, 2018-01-01 15:05=133.59999, 2018-01-01 15:10=93.3, 2018-01-01 15:15=79.25, 2018-01-01 15:20=44.300003, 2018-01-01 15:25=36.56667, 2018-01-01 15:30=43.8, 2018-01-01 15:35=39.3, 2018-01-01 15:40=39.5, 2018-01-01 15:45=33.05, 2018-01-01 15:50=28.649998, 2018-01-01 15:55=26.65, 2018-01-01 16:00=16.55, 2018-01-01 16:05=7.5, 2018-01-01 16:10=0.0}","0":"2018-01-01"}
```

I will have several thousand lines of this source data and 40-100k date_time data points, can keyed arrays handle that? Should I define the comma as my line separator? (I am unsure if a comma might occur in the packet/line break texts...)
Is there a better, easier solution?

At present I have been using a text editor to process a few sample months and test my analysis ideas but this is too slow and onerous for the full data set.

My ideal output looks like (different sample data from my editing)

```
06/11/18    11:20   799     
06/11/18    11:25   744     
06/11/18    11:30   720     
06/11/18    11:35   681     
06/11/18    11:40   543     
06/11/18    11:45   350     
06/11/18    11:50   274     
06/11/18    11:55   230     
06/11/18    12:00   286     
06/11/18    12:05   435     
06/11/18    12:10   544     
06/11/18    12:15   899     
06/11/18    12:20   1187        
06/11/18    12:25   1575        
06/11/18    12:30   1362        
06/11/18    12:35   1423
```

Maybe Python is better suited but that is a bigger learning curve and lower starting knowledge point for me...

Here is my start, it gets most of the data about right BUT does not deal with a record split across 2 packets or the trailing }"

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=","};  ($1~"^201"){if (NF=2) {split($2,X,"=");print $1,X[1], X[2]}}' sample.txt
```

outputs

```
2018-01-06 15:30 39.033333
2018-01-06 15:35 34.9
2018-01-06 15:40 24.25
2018-01-06 15     NB lost data at packet break as line not starting 201
2018-01-06 15:50 0.0
2018-01-06 15:55 0.0}" NB failed to remove trailer
2018-01-07 08:25 7.8
2018-01-07 08:30 23.7
```

Just noticed my text editing version reformatted dates as dd/mm/yy while the awk has preserved the input date format. Spreadsheets will read either so I don't care about that!

For the record just ran my awk on the binary cap file and it still seems to work in the same way as the file output by strings.

Real data, as output from `strings`

````
Mac OS X 10.11.6, build 15G22010 (Darwin 15.6.0)
Dumpcap (Wireshark) 2.6.5 (v2.6.5-0-gf766965a)
host 47.91.67.66 
Mac OS X 10.11.6, build 15G22010 (Darwin 15.6.0)
.#/[CB
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 16:15:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 2432
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Charset: big5, big5-hkscs, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm13
/v/[CB
X7BP
64, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=dfd94e11c720d0a37cf8b7c8c0cc0c75|1573575311|1573575148;Path=/
/[CB
X7BP
{"1":"{2018-01-01 08:15=9.5, 2018-01-01 08:20=22.0, 2018-01-01 08:25=29.4, 2018-01-01 08:30=30.150002, 2018-01-01 08:35=35.3, 2018-01-01 08:40=42.0, 2018-01-01 08:45=77.5, 2018-01-01 08:50=62.6, 2018-01-01 08:55=62.6, 2018-01-01 09:00=75.4, 2018-01-01 09:05=61.199997, 2018-01-01 09:10=57.85, 2018-01-01 09:15=45.7, 2018-01-01 09:20=44.266666, 2018-01-01 09:25=47.2, 2018-01-01 09:30=46.8, 2018-01-01 09:35=53.2, 2018-01-01 09:40=58.2, 2018-01-01 09:45=55.600002, 2018-01-01 09:50=56.733337, 2018-01-01 09:55=62.0, 2018-01-01 10:00=66.3, 2018-01-01 10:05=62.466663, 2018-01-01 10:10=62.699997, 2018-01-01 10:15=70.3, 2018-01-01 10:20=87.1, 2018-01-01 10:25=88.24999, 2018-01-01 10:30=102.5, 2018-01-01 10:35=95.46667, 2018-01-01 10:40=100.73334, 2018-01-01 10:45=100.700005, 2018-01-01 10:50=102.06667, 2018-01-01 10:55=116.4, 20
/[CB
X7BP
18-01-01 11:00=126.7, 2018-01-01 11:05=125.166664, 2018-01-01 11:10=128.26666, 2018-01-01 11:15=125.43333, 2018-01-01 11:20=119.666664, 2018-01-01 11:25=116.649994, 2018-01-01 11:30=94.700005, 2018-01-01 11:35=101.7, 2018-01-01 11:40=95.13333, 2018-01-01 11:45=98.76666, 2018-01-01 11:50=98.466675, 2018-01-01 11:55=92.43334, 2018-01-01 12:00=85.96667, 2018-01-01 12:05=77.833336, 2018-01-01 12:10=75.95, 2018-01-01 12:15=67.75, 2018-01-01 12:20=57.699997, 2018-01-01 12:25=74.2, 2018-01-01 12:30=87.1, 2018-01-01 12:35=77.6, 2018-01-01 12:40=74.1, 2018-01-01 12:45=63.36667, 2018-01-01 12:50=59.300003, 2018-01-01 12:55=76.9, 2018-01-01 13:00=66.6, 2018-01-01 13:05=203.4, 2018-01-01 13:10=203.45, 2018-01-01 13:15=203.45, 2018-01-01 13:20=157.3, 2018-01-01 13:25=101.333336, 2018-01-01 13:30=96.45, 2018-01-01 13:35=81.3, 2018-01-01 13:40=93.7, 2018-01-01 13:45=127.9, 2018-01-01 13:50=176.1, 2018-01-01 13:55=152.0, 2018-01-01 14:00=169.6, 2018-01-01 14:05=203.2, 2018-01-01 14:10=257.5, 2018-01-01 14:15=261.30002, 2018-01-01 14:20=261.3, 2018-01-01 14:25=218.13335, 2018-01-01 14:30=385.5, 2018-01-01 14:35=287.5, 2018-01-01 14:40=248.35002, 2018-01-01 14:45=98.2, 2018-01-01 14:50=136.2, 2018-01-01 14:55=160.0, 2018-01-01 15:00=148.1
/[CB
X7BP
, 2018-01-01 15:05=133.59999, 2018-01-01 15:10=93.3, 2018-01-01 15:15=79.25, 2018-01-01 15:20=44.300003, 2018-01-01 15:25=36.56667, 2018-01-01 15:30=43.8, 2018-01-01 15:35=39.3, 2018-01-01 15:40=39.5, 2018-01-01 15:45=33.05, 2018-01-01 15:50=28.649998, 2018-01-01 15:55=26.65, 2018-01-01 16:00=16.55, 2018-01-01 16:05=7.5, 2018-01-01 16:10=0.0}","0":"2018-01-01"}
/[CB
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 16:15:14 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 2184
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Charset: big5, big5-hkscs, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm13
/q/[CB
64, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=dfd94e11c720d0a37cf8b7c8c0cc0c75|1573575314|1573575148;Path=/
/[CB
{"1":"{2018-01-02 08:35=0.0, 2018-01-02 08:40=6.6, 2018-01-02 08:45=6.35, 2018-01-02 08:50=7.8, 2018-01-02 08:55=6.9, 2018-01-02 09:00=12.2, 2018-01-02 09:05=18.3, 2018-01-02 09:10=25.9, 2018-01-02 09:15=26.15, 2018-01-02 09:20=40.0, 2018-01-02 09:25=36.45, 2018-01-02 09:30=36.450005, 2018-01-02 09:35=30.633333, 2018-01-02 09:40=41.4, 2018-01-02 09:45=44.1, 2018-01-02 09:50=53.9, 2018-01-02 09:55=66.2, 2018-01-02 10:00=75.6, 2018-01-02 10:05=70.1, 2018-01-02 10:10=72.05, 2018-01-02 10:15=54.0, 2018-01-02 10:20=40.55, 2018-01-02 10:25=40.549995, 2018-01-02 10:30=31.699997, 2018-01-02 10:35=33.8, 2018-01-02 10:40=47.6, 2018-01-02 10:45=40.699997, 2018-01-02 10:50=36.65, 2018-01-02 10:55=19.55, 2018-01-02 11:00=12.1, 2018-01-02 11:05=9.549999, 2018-01-02 11:10=25.9, 2018-01-02 11:15=30.0, 2018-01-02 11:20=52.3, 2018-01-0
/[CB
2 11:25=63.3, 2018-01-02 11:30=97.1, 2018-01-02 11:35=147.7, 2018-01-02 11:40=163.8, 2018-01-02 11:45=186.8, 2018-01-02 11:50=241.0, 2018-01-02 11:55=289.9, 2018-01-02 12:00=265.45, 2018-01-02 12:05=247.70001, 2018-01-02 12:10=204.5, 2018-01-02 12:15=206.59999, 2018-01-02 12:20=207.83333, 2018-01-02 12:25=201.36665, 2018-01-02 12:30=189.93333, 2018-01-02 12:35=185.30002, 2018-01-02 12:40=151.65, 2018-01-02 12:45=222.9, 2018-01-02 12:50=197.65, 2018-01-02 12:55=199.46667, 2018-01-02 13:00=254.3, 2018-01-02 13:05=337.7, 2018-01-02 13:10=296.06668, 2018-01-02 13:15=308.80002, 2018-01-02 13:20=314.9, 2018-01-02 13:25=348.0, 2018-01-02 13:30=378.6, 2018-01-02 13:35=356.06665, 2018-01-02 13:40=360.1, 2018-01-02 13:45=287.86667, 2018-01-02 13:50=262.6, 2018-01-02 13:55=265.80002, 2018-01-02 14:00=256.53333, 2018-01-02 14:05=251.90001, 2018-01-02 14:10=158.45, 2018-01-02 14:15=117.0, 2018-01-02 14:20=99.5, 2018-01-02 14:25=91.25, 2018-01-02 14:30=94.1, 2018-01-02 14:35=95.55, 2018-01-02 14:40=91.666664, 2018-01-02 14:45=87.23334, 2018-01-02 14:50=81.66667, 2018-01-02 14:55=79.166664, 2018-01-02 15:00=75.333336, 2018-01-02 15:05=72.850006, 2018-01-02 15:10=60.300003, 2018-01-02 15:15=43.75, 2018-01-02 15:20=30.0, 2018-01-02 15:25
2t/[CB
=18.2, 2018-01-02 15:30=11.0, 2018-01-02 15:35=7.0, 2018-01-02 15:40=3.3, 2018-01-02 15:45=1.55}","0":"2018-01-02"}
/[CB
X>~P```


Get the full file of a month or so data here 

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vb6g9ywlgt7isw/dayData2.txt?dl=1`
````

Comment: This is so chaotic. Is the presented output generated from the input presented? Can you post a bit more blocks? Which line from the output is which line from the input? How  did you get those `06/11/18` numbers?  I see in the input there are dates like `2018-01-08`. Where from is the `799`? Can you post the output that will match the input you presented (and at best add a little input), so that I can test it easily? i think I'll do it in sed.

Comment: yes, sorry have to admit I have not been consistent with my data samples and just grabbed bits I had at hand. I just noticed the date reformatting just before your post arrived. I don't use sed much but suspect it may be a good tool for this one.

Comment: So ex. the `2018-01-08 08:50=4.5` should be transformed into `08/01/18 08:50 4.5`, eight? But what to do with that `2018-01-08 11:30=76/CB`? Should it result in `08/01/18 11:30=76`?

Comment: The /CB should be ignored and the remainder of the decimal on the next line appended. My awk are now working OK on full valid data points but not handling the splits at all. The date reformat was just an unintended side effect of some step I did by hand...

Comment: so it would be ```2018-01-08 11:30=76.54995```

Comment: Can we just remove the lines like `/[CB
$e/QM`? Like remove lines that are `/[CB` + the next line? Then concatenate the rest of lines? The `/[CB` looks like some magic newline separator inserted by some tool. For me link is fine, but you could insert here like 5~6 blocks I think would be enough.

Comment: Unsure how I should best post some full real sample data. The file could be a fair size so messy in the posting. A DropBox link? For the binary pcap file?

Comment: Trouble is I think the characters between packets vary, certainly in the binary PCAP file which has extra non printing bytes. I need to put up a decent sample...

Comment: @KamilCuk - I think the packet separator will contain rather arbitrary TCP/IP packet framing or checking data.

Comment: Ach, that is a packet separator. It has to have some format, then I can match it with a regex and remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code that uses GNU `sed` with recreated input as a stream as here doc separated with `END_OF_INPUT`, with some comments:

```
cat <<'END_OF_INPUT' |
Path=/
/[CB
$e/N
{"1":"{2018-01-08 08:50=4.5, 2018-01-08 08:55=9.5, 2018-01-08 11:30=76
/[CB
$e/QM
.549995, 2018-01-08 11:35=73.9, 2018-01-08 11:40=65.93333, 2018-01-08 15:30=2.25, 2018-01-08 15:40=0.0}","0":"2018-01-08"}
/[CB
$e/Vq
XT2P

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"1":"{2018-01-01 08:15=9.5, 2018-01-01 08:20=22.0, 2018-01-01 08:25=29.4, 2018-01-01 08:30=30.150002, 2018-01-01 08:35=35.3, 2018-01-01 08:40=42.0, 2018-01-01 08:45=77.5, 2018-01-01 08:50=62.6, 2018-01-01 08:55=62.6, 2018-01-01 09:00=75.4, 2018-01-01 09:05=61.199997, 2018-01-01 09:10=57.85, 2018-01-01 09:15=45.7, 2018-01-01 09:20=44.266666, 2018-01-01 09:25=47.2, 2018-01-01 09:30=46.8, 2018-01-01 09:35=53.2, 2018-01-01 09:40=58.2, 2018-01-01 09:45=55.600002, 2018-01-01 09:50=56.733337, 2018-01-01 09:55=62.0, 2018-01-01 10:00=66.3, 2018-01-01 10:05=62.466663, 2018-01-01 10:10=62.699997, 2018-01-01 10:15=70.3, 2018-01-01 10:20=87.1, 2018-01-01 10:25=88.24999, 2018-01-01 10:30=102.5, 2018-01-01 10:35=95.46667, 2018-01-01 10:40=100.73334, 2018-01-01 10:45=100.700005, 2018-01-01 10:50=102.06667, 2018-01-01 10:55=116.4, 20
/[CB
X7BP
18-01-01 11:00=126.7, 2018-01-01 11:05=125.166664, 2018-01-01 11:10=128.26666, 2018-01-01 11:15=125.43333, 2018-01-01 11:20=119.666664, 2018-01-01 11:25=116.649994, 2018-01-01 11:30=94.700005, 2018-01-01 11:35=101.7, 2018-01-01 11:40=95.13333, 2018-01-01 11:45=98.76666, 2018-01-01 11:50=98.466675, 2018-01-01 11:55=92.43334, 2018-01-01 12:00=85.96667, 2018-01-01 12:05=77.833336, 2018-01-01 12:10=75.95, 2018-01-01 12:15=67.75, 2018-01-01 12:20=57.699997, 2018-01-01 12:25=74.2, 2018-01-01 12:30=87.1, 2018-01-01 12:35=77.6, 2018-01-01 12:40=74.1, 2018-01-01 12:45=63.36667, 2018-01-01 12:50=59.300003, 2018-01-01 12:55=76.9, 2018-01-01 13:00=66.6, 2018-01-01 13:05=203.4, 2018-01-01 13:10=203.45, 2018-01-01 13:15=203.45, 2018-01-01 13:20=157.3, 2018-01-01 13:25=101.333336, 2018-01-01 13:30=96.45, 2018-01-01 13:35=81.3, 2018-01-01 13:40=93.7, 2018-01-01 13:45=127.9, 2018-01-01 13:50=176.1, 2018-01-01 13:55=152.0, 2018-01-01 14:00=169.6, 2018-01-01 14:05=203.2, 2018-01-01 14:10=257.5, 2018-01-01 14:15=261.30002, 2018-01-01 14:20=261.3, 2018-01-01 14:25=218.13335, 2018-01-01 14:30=385.5, 2018-01-01 14:35=287.5, 2018-01-01 14:40=248.35002, 2018-01-01 14:45=98.2, 2018-01-01 14:50=136.2, 2018-01-01 14:55=160.0, 2018-01-01 15:00=148.1
/[CB
X7BP
, 2018-01-01 15:05=133.59999, 2018-01-01 15:10=93.3, 2018-01-01 15:15=79.25, 2018-01-01 15:20=44.300003, 2018-01-01 15:25=36.56667, 2018-01-01 15:30=43.8, 2018-01-01 15:35=39.3, 2018-01-01 15:40=39.5, 2018-01-01 15:45=33.05, 2018-01-01 15:50=28.649998, 2018-01-01 15:55=26.65, 2018-01-01 16:00=16.55, 2018-01-01 16:05=7.5, 2018-01-01 16:10=0.0}","0":"2018-01-01"}
END_OF_INPUT
# preprocessing
# ignore until {"1":"{
# stop collecting at }","0":"2018-01-01"} 
sed -E -n '/\{"1":"\{/,/\}","0":"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"\}/p' |
# remove the /[CB + the next line + one newline more
sed -E '/\/\[CB/{N;d;n;}' |
# we shoudld get nice {"1":.....} lines here
# elements are separated by comma
# so we can just be cruel
tr ',' '\n' |
# now each line will have one date
# so for each data in line
# output it in our format(TM)
sed -E -n '
    /.*[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})=([0-9]*.[0-9]*).*/{
        s!!\3/\2/\1  \4  \5!
        p
    }
'
```

Will output:

```
08/01/18  08:50  4.5
08/01/18  08:55  9.5
08/01/18  11:30  76
08/01/18  11:35  73.9
08/01/18  11:40  65.93333
08/01/18  15:30  2.25
08/01/18  15:40  0.0
01/01/18  08:15  9.5
01/01/18  08:20  22.0
01/01/18  08:25  29.4
01/01/18  08:30  30.150002
01/01/18  08:35  35.3
01/01/18  08:40  42.0
01/01/18  08:45  77.5
01/01/18  08:50  62.6
01/01/18  08:55  62.6
01/01/18  09:00  75.4
01/01/18  09:05  61.199997
01/01/18  09:10  57.85
01/01/18  09:15  45.7
01/01/18  09:20  44.266666
01/01/18  09:25  47.2
01/01/18  09:30  46.8
01/01/18  09:35  53.2
01/01/18  09:40  58.2
01/01/18  09:45  55.600002
01/01/18  09:50  56.733337
01/01/18  09:55  62.0
01/01/18  10:00  66.3
01/01/18  10:05  62.466663
01/01/18  10:10  62.699997
01/01/18  10:15  70.3
01/01/18  10:20  87.1
01/01/18  10:25  88.24999
01/01/18  10:30  102.5
01/01/18  10:35  95.46667
01/01/18  10:40  100.73334
01/01/18  10:45  100.700005
01/01/18  10:50  102.06667
01/01/18  10:55  116.4
01/01/18  11:05  125.166664
01/01/18  11:10  128.26666
01/01/18  11:15  125.43333
01/01/18  11:20  119.666664
01/01/18  11:25  116.649994
01/01/18  11:30  94.700005
01/01/18  11:35  101.7
01/01/18  11:40  95.13333
01/01/18  11:45  98.76666
01/01/18  11:50  98.466675
01/01/18  11:55  92.43334
01/01/18  12:00  85.96667
01/01/18  12:05  77.833336
01/01/18  12:10  75.95
01/01/18  12:15  67.75
01/01/18  12:20  57.699997
01/01/18  12:25  74.2
01/01/18  12:30  87.1
01/01/18  12:35  77.6
01/01/18  12:40  74.1
01/01/18  12:45  63.36667
01/01/18  12:50  59.300003
01/01/18  12:55  76.9
01/01/18  13:00  66.6
01/01/18  13:05  203.4
01/01/18  13:10  203.45
01/01/18  13:15  203.45
01/01/18  13:20  157.3
01/01/18  13:25  101.333336
01/01/18  13:30  96.45
01/01/18  13:35  81.3
01/01/18  13:40  93.7
01/01/18  13:45  127.9
01/01/18  13:50  176.1
01/01/18  13:55  152.0
01/01/18  14:00  169.6
01/01/18  14:05  203.2
01/01/18  14:10  257.5
01/01/18  14:15  261.30002
01/01/18  14:20  261.3
01/01/18  14:25  218.13335
01/01/18  14:30  385.5
01/01/18  14:35  287.5
01/01/18  14:40  248.35002
01/01/18  14:45  98.2
01/01/18  14:50  136.2
01/01/18  14:55  160.0
01/01/18  15:00  148.1
01/01/18  15:05  133.59999
01/01/18  15:10  93.3
01/01/18  15:15  79.25
01/01/18  15:20  44.300003
01/01/18  15:25  36.56667
01/01/18  15:30  43.8
01/01/18  15:35  39.3
01/01/18  15:40  39.5
01/01/18  15:45  33.05
01/01/18  15:50  28.649998
01/01/18  15:55  26.65
01/01/18  16:00  16.55
01/01/18  16:05  7.5
01/01/18  16:10  0.0
```

In one command with GNU `sed` that supports `\n` as a newline:

```
sed -E -n '
    /\{"1":"\{/,/\}","0":"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"\}/{
      # remove the /[CB + the next line + one newline more
      /\/\[CB/{N;d;n;}

      : loop
     /([^\n]*)[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})=([0-9]*.[0-9]*)([^\n]*)/{
        # put the interesting string on the end of the pattern space
        s!!\1\7\n\4/\3/\2  \5  \6!
        # again, until nothing interesting is found
        b loop
    }
    # remove everything in front of the newline that we did not parse
    s/[^\n]*\n//
    # output
    p
} '
```

Comment: I tried this on the binary PCAP and step1 gave `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
` Used on the output .txt from `strings` step one was OK... but produced no output: this was maybe due to extra header text before the {"1":{

Comment: You are on macos? Set LC_CTYPE=C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x Or install GNU sed with that brew.

Comment: I am. Set that, but still no output from `sed -E -n '/\{"1":"\{/,/\}","0":"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"\}/p' DayData2.txt

Comment: not always 1 line after /[CB :  (not allowed to paste much) ```, 2018-01-06 11:05=446.13333, 2
-'/[CB
$e/-
XIXP
018-01-06 11:10=449.9, 2018-01-06 11:15=428.5,``` this was 3 lines, repeated  between more than one packets. Loss of \n may be an artefact from cut/paste into these boxes?

Comment: see dropbox link added to original question...?

Comment: Unsure what gives with the set LC_CTYPE: ```$ echo $LC_CTYPE
C```
and yet ```$ locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Just tried your sed/tr sequence but removing the first -n flag to sed. IT RAN GREAT! The second sed still had -n flag so I do not understand. Reran command adding back first -n : no output!

Comment: Accepting this answer since I am getting what I need, despite the odd change in switches. Nicely commented what each step is! THANKS! Now to work out what devices should be automated when from the data analysis (using pivot tables).

Comment: can you explain the final `s!!\3/\2/\1  \4  \5!` and  why the `p` on its own line?

Comment: The `p` is for printing the output. `-n` there is, so the output will not print until explicitly  printed with `p`. Empty replacement string `s!!` means that the "last used" regex is used, ie. the one between `/` `/` above. So it's the same as `s!.*[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})=([0-9]*.[0-9]*).*!\3/\2/\1 \4 \5!` but with less typing. The `\3 \1 \4` are backreferences to `(...)` expressions. The `!` is a separator for `s` command I chose  because it's not used anywhere, you can pick any character, ex. `s@this@that@` or `s$replace_this$for_this$`. The `/` is used.

Comment: This has been instructive, thanks. How hard is it to combine all the pieces into one script in sed? Would it be best as a `-f reformat.sed` command file?

Comment: BTW I now know what the likely yield of power and best patterns of making use of my PV power for weeks near the winter solstice are for domestic water heating on a timer. Saving a little bit of carbon burning and planetary warming!

Comment: Build `gsed` here and tried it. Seem to only get first packet data for a date and then have unwanted header...```13/02/19  09:45  354.15
13/02/19  09:50  338.06665
13/02/19  09:55  419.2
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 16:22:13 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 3213
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Charset: big5, big5-hkscs, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, etc```

Comment: ...note that data stopped at 9:55 am so not many reads at all, that seen on all days I looked at. Discard clause not working? or handling the packet break? or loop should include [CB line?

Answer (score 1):

KamilCuk has provided a best solution. The first solution with a series of commands does the best job but is not convenient to use as it stands, also it will not operate on the binary cap file.
The combined `sed` command, his solution 2, does not work so well. Probably because it works with one line pattern at a time and the multiline problems are not well catered for. Maybe it could be fixed up if the read point can be backed up a line or the residual of the last line saved and included with the next.

My own quick and lossy (more later) is a convenient one liner. It works on the binary cap file, which would allow it to accept a pipe from `tcpdump` or `ngrep` - also useful options.

Comparing my lossy solution: it lost about 1% of data points that were split across IP packets, it allowed me to also reject 1% of packets that were at the shutdown of PV system and just recording 0.0 watts.

In terms of my aims of analysing trends and probabilities in power output over times and seasons  (which I will do in buckets of 15 or 30 mins, also combining days within week_from_solstice e.g. days 14-7 before and 7-14 after 21 Dec) the loss of a few readings does not matter. The removal of the zeros at day end actually improves my data analysis.

So next time I process a sample of data via IP capture I think I might use:

`awk 'BEGIN{RS=","};  ($1~"^201"){if (NF=2) {split($2,X,"="); if (0+X[2] > 0) {split($1,D,"-");print D[3]"/"D[2]"/"substr(D[1],3,2),X[1], 0+X[2]}}}'`

`0+X[2]` required since some lines end 0.0}", the calculation both gets a number 0 from this and discards the }".

If I do not want to reformat the date (Excel takes 2018-01-31) the command is simpler:

`awk 'BEGIN{RS=","};  ($1~"^201"){if (NF=2) {split($2,X,"="); if (0+X[2] > 0) {print $1,X[1], 0+X[2]}}}'`

The command also removes responses where the database has no data (comms were down or they purged it), the IP feed then sends "2017-12-25 10:10 null"