# I have no direct access to code but wonder if I can append my chart data points to a log file

Tags: javascript, browser, highcharts

**Background**

A Chinese company that provides PV systems uses highcharts to present data for users. They are moving us to a newer code base Highcharts JS v7.2.0 (2019-09-03). 
In the old system, Highcharts JS v3.0.10 (2014-03-10), I could catch all data points in packets on my network with Wireshark while I stepped through displaying N days of data and then process the capture file to get all date, times and wattage values for my longer term analysis.

In the new system the daily data is passed in TLS as a zip file, I think this is part of the new code base feature set. It is more efficient but I can't get to see my data.
The Chinese do not provide any export to CSV, Excel options (just pdf, SVG pictures), and anyway I do not really want a file to process for each day if I am working through 60 to 300 days of data. (I have emailed them previously that they might like to add export the detailed data, and add drill down from month to day view etc both of which which I now see is supported in Highchart.)
I'm not holding my breath on that...

**My Question**

What is the easiest or best way, if any, to add some extra code in the page to append chart title, series data x&y values for each chart displayed to a file I can set at some initial point. Ideally only on first rendering to avoid getting multiple dumps of the data when the system auto-refreshes on a timer - in case I have left the recorder running!

**To clarify** I do **not** have any control of or access to the code at the server that embeds the protected TLS/zip data stream and highchair setup - it all happens in another country. To access the data values all I can think of is that I need to use some sort of console print / edit / function overload / event handler /greaseMonkey script etc I can inject/modify/add into the highchart code somehow in my browser (Safari, but I could use Firefox) after that code and data is received. I cannot see the data at all in the new system as it is behind TLS and in a zip file; all I get to see is a graph. I am not keen to add Export to CSV to the chart menu options as I do not want to have to save and work with N files...

You can see my processing and data from the old highchart based system here (where I could capture data off wifi) [Best way to pull repeated table data from a pcap http file (could awk handle the disruptive breaks)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58835793/best-way-to-pull-repeated-table-data-from-a-pcap-http-file-could-awk-handle-the)

Having dug about a little in last 14 days I am wondering if my browser can create a file stream object once and then append to that somehow when Highcharts has each data point:

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var logStream = fs.createWriteStream('PVlog.txt', {flags: 'a'});
 // use {flags: 'a'} to append and {flags: 'w'} to erase and write a new file
```

.... somewhere in Highcharts execution log my data (date, time, power) so something like:

```
 logStream.write(it.heading, it.x, it.y);
```

Comment: As I understood - are you getting just a pdf or SVG with chart rendered via using the Highcharts library and you want to set chart etc. in those files? From your description, I think that the best option will be using an addPoint feature, but I don't know if you are able to implement it... addPoint API and demos: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

Comment: Someone in China created a service on their servers that I login to and then use to see data about my PV panels. They have configured Highcharts to offer pdf/SVG images of charts but I need to collect and store the actual data points sent from server to client and then used by js to draw the chart.  See my edit at the end of question which links to processing the data on old system, I think it will help!

Comment: Thanks for more information. Are you able to reproduce a simulation of your process in some online editor? I mean - just a sample piece of your data to see how it looks like. Here is an example of how I understood it from your description: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sxcbuor5/ please edit it to clarify more your issue.

Comment: Sorry but I have no access to the data or Highchart code, other than looking at the page source code in my browser - which is where I noticed the use of Highchart. So I cannot provide any source data for the jsfiddle you created. I have tried to clarify this in the last 2 paragraphs of the question. Sorry for 2 day delay, was not able to make time for this.

Comment: Now I am sorry for the 2-day delay. Let's try this one if Highcharts are defined in the window object it should work. So, go to the website where charts are rendering, open the dev console and paste Highcharts.chart[0] where 0 is a number of the first chart. In the object, you can find the whole chart config. Go to Highcharts.chart[0].series[number of series] and in this object you can find a data object or array with xData or yData. You can test it on this page: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic and paste: Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].data, the data array will be available in cons

Comment: I could access the series in your test page but not a chart in the real web data I want. Highcharts.chart[0] did not seem to be found as an object, I was not sure if there would be another way to find an element. I tried a few guesses and failed... Completions(>) existed for High>charts, and .cha>rt(s) so those exist. If working this would be too slow as a way to get 300days of data from 300 charts... but a first step is always needed for progress :-)

Is ther a way to extend the "draw_point" functionality so it draws the data point and appends the data to a log file?

Comment: NB to REVIEWER etc. I have received warnings in the past about a conversational outcome (as the above is sort of becoming). But my attempt to add my last point above to the question were rejected by reviewers... How do we best move towards finding and sharing solutions when multiple steps are required?

Comment: Is ther a way to extend the "draw_point" functionality so it draws the data point and appends the data to a log file? - yes, it is possible but it needs to be attached to the website source on the server site. Are you able to share this webpage?

Comment: Aa I mentioned I have no access to the manufacturers servers. Best is I can make a local copy of the page and modify that but I have to have a logged in session running and have no information how/where that resides. My other thought was something like Greasemonkey adding code into Mozilla Firefox hosted session. If you could suggest some code I could try and find a way apply it. I will see if I can get a local copy of the page operating - you would see code but not run it I suspect... Is the file stream code I added to question near what might work?

Comment: I see... I am trying to help you from the Highcharts support site - that's my job. But I am afraid that I cannot help you more without access to your application. If you will be able to get a local copy try to paste this render function which will console log points for each series: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r2nckL6t/. Hm.. What do you see when you paste Highcharts.charts in the dev console? Do you have access to Highcharts array of chart objects? If not, the page could be encoded - in this case, I am not able to help at all.

Comment: Just logged in and checked the charts object. It seems fully there now, Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].processedYData presents a nice list of data values for today for instance. Perhaps my login to the page had partly timed out previously, although the built in update timer was updating the chart? I hope to get some time to look at a local copy and your suggestions in a few days having just got back from 5 days away there is a life backlog!

Comment: If you hot access to chart object you can get the same result by pasting: Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].points. Hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping I can record progress towards getting data out, the steps taken etc. I have some progress, but far from what I would want to use for capturing significant amounts of data.

For a sample of the working of the system I am referring to try clicking on any of the available sample systems currently producing power via the "Demo account" at

https://server.growatt.com/login/toViewExamlePlant

Opening js console I have found that the system creates new entries in the charts object array when a different day is displayed. Any older chart seems to get nulled to undefined (maybe this is an less than optimal use of Highcharts):

```
Array (3)
0 undefined
1 undefined
2 Chart {renderTo: <div class="chartDiv height1">, exporting: Object, navigation: Object, userOptions: Object, margin: [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined], …}
```

So to access data in the latest current chart I have used [Highcharts.charts.length-1] to index into the charts array, which is 0 based.

For the date of data graphed my best solution so far is to examine the tooltip configuration:

```
 console.log(Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].tooltip.options.userOptions.headerFormat)
 example output for 4 Jan 2020: 
<span style="font-size:10px">2020-01-04 {point.key}</span><table>
```

For data point values:

```
console.log(Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].yData)
Seeing the end of data is awkward as long data in console truncates end in ellipsis… 
right-click > copy object       SORT OF works with paste giving:
[Log] Array (16)
0 11.9
1 10.549999
2 18.8
3 18.05
4 21
5 29.7
6 38
7 37.6
8 66.4
9 83.1
10 75.46667
11 100
12 89.666664
13 96.833336
14 94.03333
15 92.26666
```

For the X axis categories, showing the times of day for each reading:

```
console.log(Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].xAxis.categories)
As before     right-click > copy object         SORT OF works with paste giving:
[Log] Array (71)
0 "09:05"
1 "09:10"
2 "09:15"
3 "09:20"
4 "09:25"
5 "09:30"
6 "09:35"
7 "09:40"
8 "09:45"
9 "09:50"
10 "09:55"
11 "10:00"
12 "10:05"
13 "10:10"
14 "10:15"
15 "10:20"
```

So far this is really only first steps proof that I can get at the data. It is very clunky to use and would require considerable further work!

The first step would be to create a function to call that can obtain all the data in one go, ideally formatting the data ready for combining with other days of data, tab separated. Any standard date format would be fine too, e.g. 2018-11-30 as used in the tooltip:

```
06/11/18    11:20   799     
06/11/18    11:25   744     
06/11/18    11:30   720     
06/11/18    11:35   681     
06/11/18    11:40   543     
06/11/18    11:45   350     
06/11/18    11:50   274     
06/11/18    11:55   230     
06/11/18    12:00   286     
06/11/18    12:05   435     
06/11/18    12:10   544     
06/11/18    12:15   899     
06/11/18    12:20   1187        
06/11/18    12:25   1575        
06/11/18    12:30   1362        
06/11/18    12:35   1423
```

My next aim would be to get that data appended to a single file, myPV_DataFile.txt by a single Console command, better would be automatically on "pageLoaded" or "chart_draw_completed" being signalled.

Next step forward for me:

```
for(q = 0; q < Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].yData.length; q++) {console.log(Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].xAxis.categories[q], Math.round(Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].yData[q]))}
```

Which produces x_category,y_value pairs in the log, they do not seem to be easily copy/pasted though.

Thanks to https://github.com/edubey/browser-console-crawl/blob/master/single-story.js

... next step is to create console.save () function, and then a few lines to save the data as I want. TBH I was surprised the console would allow this much!

```
console.save = function (data, filename) {
    if (!data) {
        console.error('Console.save: No data')
        return;
    }

    if (!filename) filename = 'story.json'

    if (typeof data === "object") {
        data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
    }

    var blob = new Blob([data], {
            type: 'text/json'
        }),
        e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a = document.createElement('a')

    a.download = filename
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    a.dispatchEvent(e)
}

myPV = Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].tooltip.options.userOptions.headerFormat+"\n";
for(q = 0; q < Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].yData.length; q++) {myPV+=Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].xAxis.categories[q] +", "+ Math.round(Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].yData[q])+"\n"}
console.save(myPV, "QQsample3.txt")
```

Next step to strip out just the date from the headerFormat and use that as my filename, maybe. The the lot can be put in myGet function although it will still ask me to confirm each file name and save step in the UI. Sure that can be bypassed later!

Simple function can do the job for me, but is lost from console session if I refresh the page:

```
mySave = function () {
var myDate=Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].tooltip.options.userOptions.headerFormat.substring(29,40);
myPV = myDate+"\n";
for(q = 0; q < Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].yData.length; q++) {myPV+=Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].xAxis.categories[q] +", "+ Math.round(Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].yData[q])+"\n"}
console.save(myPV, myDate+".txt")
}
```

This produces a file like 2020-01-07.txt :

```
2020-01-07 
08:20, 16
08:25, 25
08:30, 42
08:35, 66
08:40, 67
08:45, 65
08:50, 64
08:55, 72
09:00, 112
09:05, 147
09:10, 148
09:15, 165
09:20, 223
09:25, 209
09:30, 202
09:35, 188
09:40, 176
09:45, 225
09:50, 276
09:55, 325
10:00, 300
10:05, 281
10:10, 216
10:15, 203
10:20, 205
etc.
```

I've not really used js much before so pleased to get to this relatively easily. Ideally I'd want the functions to persist better, and secondly to trigger the saving via some update_completed event in the Highcharts (re-)drawing or other page event.

Knowing the best, or possible, ways to approach my final 2 goals probably requires more background knowledge than I will acquire in a few days!