# iOS9 Untrusted Enterprise Developer with no option to trust

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-enterprise

This is not a duplicate of [Untrusted App Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719713/untrusted-app-developer-message-when-installing-enterprise-ios-application). Since iOS9 there is no option to trust an enterprise build. Has anyone found a workaround?

[image]

Comment: The answer to this question is wrong !!! if it wasn't protected I'd be able to update it to the correct solution Settings -> General -> Device Management -> Pick from list -> Select Trust "developer"

Comment: The amount of time I had (and still have to) spend on the phone telling our customers that it's not a bug but in fact a new safety alert introduced by Apple that I, as a developer, can _NOT_ disable/accept by default. Sigh.

Comment: Related: [iOS Untrusted Developer error when testing app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/206143/22781)

Answer (score 783, accepted):

In iOS 9.1 and lower, go to *Settings - General - Profiles* - tap on your *Profile* - tap on *Trust* button.

In iOS 9.2+ & iOS 11+ go to: *Settings - General - Profiles & Device Management* - tap on your *Profile* - tap on *Trust* button.

In iOS 10+, go to: *Settings - General - Device Management* - tap on your *Profile* - tap on *Trust* button.

Comment: I already have an existing MDM profile from my company's email system, and when I go to Settings / General, there is only "Profile" which has this one profile. How can I get the developer certificate to show up here?

Comment: Beta 3 broke this solution

Comment: Profile menu is missing in beta 3. Actually I tried to install "Watch OS" profile so the profile menu pops up. Now I have the profile menu but my ID is missing. I am really confused now.

Comment: If you can't find Profile menu item, send the provisioning profile through email and open that email on your iOS device and tap the attached provisioning profile.

Comment: @36ByDesign The answer *does* work in Beta 3. There was a bug (or bugs) in previous betas that caused the Profiles button to sporadically disappear, but it looks like Beta 3 fixed it.

Comment: Beta 4 broke this solution too - no profiles menu at all and no option to trust. What a ...

Comment: But in my case there is no profile for Myapp in profile section to tap..! Any help please ?

Comment: This should be in a popup when the app is started, not rely on having to delve several layers into settings.

Comment: I also didn't have the Profiles menu initially, but restarting the device solved it.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid doing those steps? If the users who use the app don't know how to do those step?

Comment: I have the official iOS 9 release and this seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a clumsy solution though, I wonder why Apple doesn't add a 'Trust' button to the dialog in the first place...

Comment: @Paludis - I imagine their goal was to minimize the number of people sideloading apps onto their iPhone. It sets up a small barrier that's rather trivial for a developer (we know to just check StackOverflow) that is a bit more tricky for the average person who just wants to run an app that isn't from the app store.

Comment: I don't seem to have Settings - General - Profiles on my iPad. IOS 9.1

Comment: I used iOS 9.2.1 , this suggestion works perfect. Thank you @Alexander

Comment: is there any way to trust the application using itunes or pc?

Comment: Is there a solution for iOS 9.3.5?

Comment: Works on iOS 9.3.2

Answer (score 128):

Do it like this:

[image]

Go to *Settings* -> *General* -> *Profiles* - tap on your Profile - tap on the *Trust* button.

but iOS10 has a little change,

Users should go to Settings - General - Device Management - tap on your Profile - tap on Trust button.

[image]

Reference: [iOS10AdaptationTips](https://github.com/ChenYilong/iOS10AdaptationTips#ios10-dealing-with-untrusted-enterprise-developer)

Comment: but on device there is no such profile installed in profile section,then what to do? and device is on remote location on iOS 9 beta...!

Comment: @RahulShirphule Please see my comment below. :) You'll have to open Xcode

Answer (score 19):

For iOS 9 beta 3,4 users. Since the option to view profiles is not viewable do the following from Xcode.

1. Open Xcode 7.
2. Go to window, devices.
3. Select your device.
4. Delete all of the profiles loaded on the device.
5. Delete the old app on your device.
6. Clean and rebuild the app to your device.

On iOS 9.1+ n iOS 9.2+ go to Settings -> General -> Device Management -> press the Profile -> Press Trust.

Comment: what to do if the device on remote location? I create ipa with distribution provision profile and send them. Any suggestion ?

Comment: This actually sort of worked for me. Provisioning profiles are hidden behind gear button at the bottom left corner. I still cannot run the app using development profile though.

Answer (score 16):

**Changes to Enterprise App Distribution Coming in iOS 9**

> iOS 9 introduces a new feature to help protect users from installing
>   in-house apps from untrusted sources. While no new app signing or
>   provisioning methods are required, the way your enterprise users
>   manage in-house apps installed on their iOS 9 devices will change.
>
> In-house apps installed using an MDM solution are explicitly trusted
>   and will no longer prompt the user to trust the developer that signed
>   and provisioned the app. If your enterprise app does not use an MDM
>   solution, users who install your app for the first time will be
>   prompted to trust the developer. All users who install your app for
>   the first time will need an internet connection.
>
> Using a new restriction, organizations can limit the apps installed on their devices to the in-house apps that they create. And a new interface in Settings allows users to see all enterprise apps installed from their organization.

[image: Changes to Enterprise App Distribution Coming in iOS 9]

*Source:* Official email sent from developer@insideapple.apple.com to existing enterprise app developers.

Comment: What is the source of this quote?

Comment: The source of the quote is an official email sent from developer@insideapple.apple.com to existing enterprise app developers. http://i.stack.imgur.com/aEAuh.png

Comment: any free MDM soltuon could be used? apple configurator ?

Comment: if I use MDM solution, will iPhone able to install application without internet connection ? @onmyway133

Answer (score 12):

**Device**: iPad Mini

**OS**: iOS 9 Beta 3

**App downloaded from**: Hockey App

**Provisioning profile with Trust issues**: Enterprise

In my case, when I navigate to  Settings > General > Profiles, I could not see on any Apple provisioning profile. All I could see is a Configuration Profile which is HockeyApp Config.

[image: Settings>General>Profile]

Here are the steps that I followed:

1. Connect the Device
2. Open Xcode
3. Navigate to Window > Devices
4. Right click on the Device and select Show Provisioning Profiles...
5. Delete your Enterprise provisioning profile. Hit Done.
   [image: Window>Device>Provisioning Profile]
6. Open HockeyApp. Install your app.
7. Once the app finished installing, go back to Settings>General>Profiles. You should now be able to see your Enterprise provisioning profile.
   [image]
8. Click Trust
   [image]

That's it! You're done! You can now go back to your app and open it successfully. Hope this helped. :)

Comment: Thank you for this, this was the only solution that worked for me. Even though the Device window is bugged a bit in Xcode 9, it still worked in the end!

Comment: Glad to be of help! :) @Vladimir

Comment: Right click did not work for me, but Ctrl-Click in Xcode.

Answer (score 10):

On iOS 9.2 `Profiles` renamed to `Device Management`.
Now navigation looks like that:
`Settings -> General -> Device Management -> Tap on necessary profile in list -> Trust.`

Comment: Is it just a visual change or a change in functionality too?

Comment: Looks like just visual changes. I didn't find any differences in behavior.