# iOS enterprise distribution using ios 9 beta with error message

Tags: ios, ios9

My app has distributing by enterprise account.

But... when I testing on iOS 9 beta, I can't install my app and it shows message "Untrusted App Developer".

What's going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS9 Untrusted Enterprise Developer with no option to trust](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Settings in device
2. Go to General
3. Go to Profiles in General section

Here you can find your application with signing identity.

You can trust your application here.

And may be there is possible of duplicate of distributing by enterprise account in your device.