# "Untrusted Developer" is there any way to trust the eterprise app without going into Settings on IOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus, ios-enterprise

I installed IOS 9 beta5 on my iphone and when i tried to run my enterprise application on IOS 9 beta5 it shows me an alert of "Untrusted Developer" with only "Cancel" option. I know i can trust my app by going into Settings-> General ->Profile and then trust my profile.

But this is not easy for end user. I am searching a way so that end user can trust the app on the home screen like before IOS 9 the alert have "Trust" button and user can tap on it to trust the application.

Is there any way that when the alert of "Untrusted Developer" appears then at that time user will have a option of "Trust" in that alert and he simply tap on "Trust" and app start running without going into Settings-> General -> Profile ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS9 Untrusted Enterprise Developer with no option to trust](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust)

Comment: Nope in above Question he is only asking about how to trust the enterprise app.

Comment: MDM solution is probably the only way. But your end user's device has to be added to your device enroll program

Comment: If i have 50k users then i have to add all user' devices to device enroll program?

Comment: in our company, we use to provide Enterprise installation to users who come to an event without even knowing their email address.

Of course they were installing the app at their own "risk", because they trusted us.

This won't be possible anymore with a simple click: the user will need to know how to authorize a developer. This is just plain stupid.

Of course we could use App Store, if only the event managers would not send us the contents of the event some hours before the event itself..

Comment: In similar situation as Fabio and Abuzar. My company has tens of thousands of employees, scattered across the world. My app is not public but can potentially be used by any of them as long as they have access to the secure site to download it. MDM is impossible.