# iOS9 Enterprise Developer apps missing Entreprise Profile

Tags: ios, ios9, mdm, ios-enterprise

i have enterprise iOs app which is i am not able to install on some iOs9 devices due to missing profile .

some devices will have the entrpesie profile installed and all that user has to do is to follow the steps in link to trust the app manually .
[iOS9 Untrusted Enterprise Developer with no option to trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust)

however , some devices won't have even the profile installed to be trusted, i am thinking about pushing the profiles to the devices before initiating the download process , using mechanism like hockeyapp and VPN apps is doing , simple a webpage with link to install the profile and once its installed then server initiates the download process .
this link https://rink.io/swyRin8 from hockeyapp is good example

any idea how to create a profile to be pushed over the air ? is it .mobileprovision file ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can push over the air. for this purpose you have to provide 2 file

1. .mobileprovision
2. .p12 file (exported from keychain)

Comment: thanks , but how to bundle them into something to be downloaded to devices ?