# Unable to Trust Enterprise Untrusted app with iOS 9.0.2

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios9

Just downloaded iOS 9.0.2 to my **NEW** iPad. When I did it said that the app wasn't trusted and that I needed to trust the app. Everything I have seen says to go to general **settings->profile->trust** the app you need to trust and then open the app and use it. When I go to general settings there is no profile listed under the settings page. I have also check many similar post before posting again

Link - [iOS9 Untrusted Enterprise Developer with no option to trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust)

Looking for help on either how to get the profile settings to show up or on how to trust and untrusted app without the profile settings. The app is running fine with old iPad which i updated to iOS 9.0.2.

Comment: Delete the app and install it again

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and found that if you have no profiles yet on a new iPad or iPhone, the option will not exist. I created a `profile` and `loaded` it into my device and the profiles option appeared.

Then even after I deleted the profile, the menu option for profiles remained.

To add provisioning profile you can go through the [apple docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW31)

Comment: Thanks Rajat will check you solution and let you know the result.