# Use enterprise licence to install app on *any* iphone

Tags: ios

Is it technically possible to use provision profile (not signed by Apple) that allows app to be run on any iPhone?

I have in-home app, should I add any new device to device lists and regenerate provision profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With enterprise account (https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) you can make build which will be installed on any device, and you do not need to add this device UDID to your list of devices. But you according to the apple's licence you can distribute this build only inside your company, or your account will be revoked.

Comment: I do have enterprise account. I did application profile (not a wildcard one), and extracted app as Enterprise, but it still works only on listed devices, just like ad hoc installation

Comment: you should use distribution certificate/profile to do this

Comment: just generate new certificate using "App Store and Ad Hoc" option and new profile with this certificate

Comment: I have distrobution profile since it is not possible to extract app for distribution with out of such profile. http://postimg.org/image/tyzs6p4kz/

Comment: thank you, I have "iOS Distribution" certificate as well

Comment: then it should work, make sure that your certificate is not expired. Also it's several types of distribution profiles exists, recreate the profile and make sure, you check the correct one

Comment: Looks like my app simply was not added to trust: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust

Answer (score 1):

No it's not.

And yes, your app will only work on devices you have added in the member center. After adding a new device, you need to :

- Regenerate you provisioning profiles (click edit and check the device you just added then save)
- Go to Xcode account preferences, click "View Details.." and refresh your account (bottom left button)
- Recompile your app.