# iOS9 Trust Enterprise Developer without internet connection

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, enterprise

In my project, I need to install application to iOS devices using a desktop EXE. I use `libimobiledevice` command to install the application and it works fine. As I use enterprise developer profile, I know I need to trust profile from Settings. To trust a profile it needs internet connection as per Apple.
[iOS9 Untrusted Enterprise Developer with no option to trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust)

But on my case, there will not be any internet connection in device, but we have internet connection in Desktop PC where the EXE runs. Is there any option to launch Enterprise IPA file without having internet connection. 
I learn MDM Apple Enterprise distribution but not sure whether it will survive my purpose.

Is there any possible way to launch the enterprise IPA without having internet connection in iOS device.

Comment: have no idea why you're doing that... try to "pre-trust" devices, if possible? Therefore users will be ready to go by the required moment? Even with different app.

Comment: actually, it will be a diagnosis tool of iphone and each time its not possible to connect internet where as device will be over thousand per day.
what do you mean by pre-trust. you mean install application earlier? is there any way to verify using exe by pinging http://ppq.apple.com ?

Comment: I know this could be a stupid question, but if it's .ipa file you need to install on a device, did you try iTunes application?

Comment: using iTunes will not work as it will sync all the data where as iPhone will be over 500 per day. and also even you install using iTunes it will, you need internet connection for the first time you launch the application to verify the app

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to verify the Enterprise Certificate in the app with Apple, as they are the ones giving you a licence to install apps outside the appstores.

That's just the way these Enterprise ID's work.

if the desktop PC's have iTunes, you could try dropping the ipa in there and see if this antique program can help you out.

Comment: using iTunes still require verification

Answer (score -1):

This would definitely require some hacking. One approach may be to edit the hosts file of the computer when installing using the executable, launching your own server to listen to the port specified in the hosts file, and replicate the response given by server in a real life scenario. (you can probably use charles or fiddler to trace the response which is suppose to be given by the server.

Basically, the verification of the cert would be done by the local server you are running.

This, of course, is quite complex as a task... good luck!

Comment: any idea what data iOS post to Apple server to verify application

Comment: Nope, you would have to sort this out, but the traffic most likely goes to itunes.com. Note, however, that doing this kind of work around probably goes against the developer agreement that you have with apple. The best solution, unfortunately, is to try to find a way to have the internet...

Comment: I would definitly not recommend hacking Apple's response. They will block your Enterprise ID and every ID linked to your organisation..

Comment: Agree with @OscarBout ... like i said its not a good idea and violating the agreement can get you banned.