# Crashlytics -> IOS APP -> Enterprise distribution profile -> Asking UDID

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am using the Crashlytics (Fabric Tool) to distribute the app. I have generated build with "Enterprise" distribution certificate, distribute the app using "Crashlytics".

But when my tester are trying to install the app, it shows the below error and it is not allow to install:

> You are all set now as soon as new build is ready, we will send you
>   an email letting you know. The developer needs to add the device UDID
>   in the build.

But I am using the "Distribution profile" and my license is "Enterprise Developer license".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fabric Crashlytics supports Enterprise Distribution profiles without UDID provisioning. I encountered the 'UDID' required problem when publishing the app through the Fabric interface. By default, it appears that Crashlytics exports builds with an Ad-Hoc distribution profile, not with an Enterprise distribution profile. The workaround is to export the application IPA binary manually with the Enterprise distribution profile in the XCode Organizer, save to disk, then use the following command line interface to upload the build to Fabric.

```
$Crashlytics_Framework_Path/Crashlytics/submit API_KEY PRIVATE_KEY 
-ipaPath [IPA file] -emails [emails to distribute to] -notifications YES
```

You will then be able to install the app via the Crashlytics link on any supported device. You will need to [manually trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust) the application developer before launching the app.

Answer (score 2):

Mike from Fabric here.

Fabric will work with Enterprise distributions, but we follow Xcode's lead for which profile to use. At times, Xcode can choose the wrong one, so I'd recommend doing a clean before your Archive and that should help ensure the correct profile is used and your app can be installed without needing the UDID.