# how do i compile my iphone in xcode4 in to a ipa

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4, cydia

I am a newbie here and i want to know how do i compile my iphone app in xcode 4 with a fake code sign?( pleaase include files if any.)

more info - i have made my iphone app in xcode 4 and tested it in the iphone simulator and all appears to be working great.

now i want to compile it for cydia submission, but when i look at the fake code sign idid on the big boss website, it is the old xcode3.

so please help me because I REALLLY WANT THIS APP TO GET OUT THERE and people to use it.

thanks.

Comment: If you are still interested, I have a tutorial of this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4423913/427309, assuming you have your codesigning figured out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a folder called Payload
2. Place the .app folder inside of that
3. Zip up the Payload folder using normal compression
4. Then rename the file with a .ipa extension

That's it! No image will appear with loading it in iTunes.

Comment: Theres a bit more to it than that, if you don't want to install it with iTunes, and I have a script that works with Xcode over at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4423913/427309