# Codesign is ok for some projects in iOS SDK 4.3 but not for others

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, codesign

I've followed the instructions in [iPhone App Minus App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store) and managed to build the AcceleratorGraph project without any problems regarding codesign. However, if I create a new project (via the new project wizard) I always get the following warnings:

1. Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
2. This bundle is invalid. The application-identifier entitlement is not formatted correctly; it should contain your 10-character App ID Seed, followed by a dot, followed by your bundle identifier: com.yourcompany.MyApp (-19053)

I've tried creating an Entitlements.plist with a bundle identifier but nothing changes.

I ve downloaded, built and successfully deployed other projects from the net, without these warnings. Is it something known with this version of Xcode 3.26/iOS SDK 4.3 ?

Comment: I don't really follow you on your issue, nor do I have any experience with XCode 3, but the method you've linked requires us to re-do some steps for every new project. Maybe [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device/4180498#4180498)  on the same subject might help you a little bit.