# iOS apps without developer license / app store

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I'm new to iPhone development and was wondering if there is a good/easy guide I could follow to install an iOS app on a jailbroken phone without joining the developer program.

Basically, I don't know if I'm going to have the time to learn everything I need to learn, but would like to make a start and see where it leads. Once I have something decent put together I can make plans to go through official channels.

I followed a guide that I found in SO, but when launching the app it immediately dies/crashes back to the springboard. So I can only assume I did something wrong, or the guide is outdated.

I'm using iOS 4.3.3 and xCode 4.

here is the link to the guide I followed: [iPhone App Minus App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store)

Thanks

Comment: I just found a guide that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device. all I had to do was change the 4.2 in one of the commands to 4.3

Comment: With Xcode 7 it's now free to run your apps on your iPhone, iPad or Apple Watch (beta). Look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to get the warning away.

I just found a guide that worked for me: [How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device). all I had to do was change the 4.2 in one of the commands to 4.3

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 7 it's now free to run your apps on your iPhone, iPad or Apple Watch (beta): https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

> Now everyone can get their app on their Apple device. Xcode 7 and
>   Swift now make it easier for everyone to build apps and run them
>   directly on their Apple devices. Simply sign in with your Apple ID,
>   and turn your idea into an app that you can touch on your iPad,
>   iPhone, or Apple Watch. Download Xcode 7 beta and try it yourself
>   today. Program membership is not required.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my own method, but I thought I'd help you out since I've just read this elsewhere:

[Answer by WrightsCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak/4953407#4953407)

> There's a way you can do this.
>
> You will need ROOT access to edit the following file.
>
> Navigation to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk and open the file SDKSettings.plist.
>
> In that file, expand DefaultProperties and change CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED to NO, while you are there, you can also change ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED to NO also.
>
> You will have to restart Xcode for the changes to take effect. Also, you must do this for every .sdk you want to be able to run on device.
>
> Now, in your project settings, you can change Code Signing Identity to Don't Code Sign.
>
> Your app should now build and install on your device successfully."

Comment: This would be helpful to me too. I changed signing & entitlements both to NO. Restarted Xcode. Project settings already said don't code sign. But it still fails to build/install on my iPod. Any ideas?

Comment: Mate, i've followed your instructions and after building app i'm getting message from XCode "No code signature found.". Do you know why i get this and how i could resolve this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: @KamilZieliński have you been able to resolve the issue. i've exactly the same problem.

Comment: @1b0t unfortunetly no. For me the only option is to buy license.