# Installing application on device without an apple developer ID

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is there a **legal** way to install my application on to other apple devices (`iPhone, iPod, iPad`) without using the `apple developer account` (without having to pay `99USD`)

Comment: Jailbreaking your phone is legal.

Comment: So then i cold install the application directly to my or other iPhones. Is there a tutorial that explains the process ?

Comment: Jailbreak it, then u can build to device w/o a key in XCode

Comment: Is there any consequences that i will have to face for Jailbreaking my iPhone ?

Comment: no one will arrest you if thats the question, but what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just need to install my application on few iPhones. The normal way of doing this is to create a provisioning profile and add the devices (for this you need a apple dev account). So i need to know another way to install my application without using the dev account (without having to pay 99 USD)

Comment: Jailbreaking is 100% legal, the only thing I feel I must add to this is, if you EVER bring your iPhone to your service provider or an Apple store for whatever reason, reformat the phone and remove the jailbreak first. They have no way of knowing if the device was jailbroken in the past but if they see it, they WILL void your warranty.

Comment: Please check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539075/ios-apps-without-developer-license-app-store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not legal, when it would be legal apple would not want you to pay 99$/year.