# How can I test my apps on my iphone for free?

Tags: iphone, flash-cs4, publishing

I want to do a apple iphone application and want to test in my iphone. 
But whenever I finished my apps and try to publish in my PC. They request Apple developer 
certificate although I want to use for myself. I can't publish my apps. 
And also I can't afford to buy Apple developer certificate.
thanks in advance.

Can you please help and advice me 
"How can I test my iphone apps on my PC?" 
I'm using Adobe Flash Cs4 professional.

Comment: If you can afford a $500+ iPhone then I am certain you can afford an Apple Developer license for a mere $99. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test your apps for free on a single device in xcode 7.x. 
Please follow the instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27/)!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer would be: You can't.

Usually you need a mac to do proper iOS development and usually (which means taking the official route) there's no way to run your app on any device without a certificate.

You might be able to run it on a jailbroken device though, but I can't tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

I think only possible by Jailbreaking your device or faking certificate.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test on device you must have an iOS Developer Program account. It cost 99US/year and you sign up at http://developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to jailbreak your phone and then create your own certificate.
Check this out [iPhone App Minus App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store) for steps on how to do that.

Of course this will only help you for testing purposes; if you want to submit to the app store then you will have to register for a developer account (99$/year)