# iOS 5 SDK with iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios4, osx-snow-leopard, ios5

OK,

I need to get into iOS development as I am an android dev and companies most times require both platforms, but I don't really have the money to invest or give to Apple. My sister upgraded her phone to an Android based one as well and she doesn't need her iPhone 3G. So my question is, wether or not can I compile code for iOS4 using the iOS5 SDK in order to test it. Also I am strounded on Snow Leopard too and the latest Xcode is only available for Lion. Is this an Apple policy and I would need to force my self to update to Lion, should I wish to carry on developing for Apple products?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think iOS5 runs on the iPhone 3g

Answer (score 2):

- The latest iOS SDK and Xcode <strike>work only on lion so you'll have to upgrade.</strike> (I was wrong here you can download the latest Xcode [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/346639/is-there-an-xcode-4-2-for-snow-leopard) )
- You can compile code and target the 4.X iOS version (but you can't install iOS 5 on the iPhone 3G nor use any iOS5 specific APIs in your application).
- You also have to spend money to be able to test on the device ($99/year), you can test without a membership ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store)) but debugging on device won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you will register as a developer and purchase iOS Developer program then:

1. Xcode 4.2 will be also available for Snow Leopard. It can be downloaded from developer.apple.com
2. You can test your applications on iPhone3G but you cannot install iOS5 on it

Answer (score 0):

Apple has in the past removed support for running the iPhone development tools on older Mac OS versions.  While there currently is an SDK download supporting the current release of iOS for a recent version of Snow Leopard, there is no guarantee on how long Apple will continue this.

Any developer who wishes to continue iOS development longer term should probably plan on acquiring access to new devices periodically and having a non-ancient Mac.