# Can XCode 4.2 run on 10.5 Leopard?

Tags: ios, macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, osx-leopard

Can XCode 4.2 run on 10.5 Leopard? 
Or will it only work with Snow Leopard (10.6) or Lion(10.7)?

Comment: Are you asking because your mac is a power PC one that can't be upgraded any higher than leopard?

Comment: No. Probably I will buy an used Mac and I needed to know witch version of Mac OS I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4.2 can run on both Snow Leopard ([direct link](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_with_ios_5_sdk/xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg)) and Lion ([App store link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12))

Comment: One stupid question (from one person that never used Mac before): 
The Xcode 4.2 is free from Mac App Store (http://developer.apple.com/xcode/) . Using a Mac, the Mac App Store is free or I need to pay to use it?

Comment: @user1041864 You don't need to pay anything to create an account to use with the app store. free applications are also 100% free to download.

Comment: So, I just need to pay the iOS Developer Program ($99/year), to test my application on real device, I can developer an entire application and test it in the emulator for free?

Comment: @user1041864 Yes. Testing on the simulator is free, testing on a real device may be done if [you're jailbroken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store). to distribute your apps and stuff, you have to pay the $99/year.

Comment: This is going probably beyond the scope of the topic, but my application will be used just by a company only (not on Apply Store), but probably will be used by more than 100 devices. To join “iOS Developer Enterprise Program ($299)” is needed company DUNS Number (I´m not a company). So the company that will use the iOS application need to do the registration and distribute to theirs employees?

Comment: @user1041864 This I don't know about, you should ask it as a separate question and someone will probably give you the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096749/deploy-ios-application-for-one-company-employees-only

Answer (score 3):

My school lab had this issue. The latest version of xcode that will run on 10.5 Leopard is 3.1 (3.1.4 is the exact version).  Anything later requires 10.6 Snow Leopard.