# Deploy iOS application for one company employees only

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment

I'm developing an iOS application that will be used just by a company employees only (not for distribution on the Apple store), but probably will be used by more than 100 devices. To join “iOS Developer Enterprise Program ($299)” is needed company DUNS Number (I´m not a company, so I don't have one).

So the company that will use the iOS application need to do the registration on “iOS Developer Enterprise Program ($299)” and have a DUNS Number to distribute the app to theirs employees? Or I cant deploy my application on more than 100 devices without the “iOS Developer Enterprise Program ($299)” (without jailbreak) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So the company that will use the iOS application need to do the
>   registration on “iOS Developer Enterprise Program ($299)” and have a
>   DUNS Number to distribute the app to theirs employees?

That's correct -- the company will join the Enterprise program and that will give them the right to distribute the app in-house. They can add you to their development team so that you can develop your code using their subscription. In the past, companies had to have something like 500 employees to qualify for the Enterprise program. That limit may have changed by now.

> Or I cant deploy my application on more than 100 devices without the
>   “iOS Developer Enterprise Program ($299)” (without jailbreak) ?

Right, and "deploy" isn't quite the right word. With a standard developer account you can test your app on up to 100 devices using 'ad hoc' distribution. That's really not meant to be a means to deploy your app, though, it's intended mainly for testing. For example, you'll probably have to update the app every few months as the provision expires.

Answer (score 2):

If you are iOS developer(individual who doesn't have DUNS number) and you are writing an App for a company who would like to distribute the app for more than 100 devices, then yes that company is required to register for an iOS developer enterprise program.

The program does require their DUNS number and a contact for their legal department.  The company must sign an agreement with Apple that they are not going to misuse the certificate. Misuse would be distributing any developed apps *outside of the company* without going through app store.

However, what you can do is sign your app with your individual ad-hoc distribution certificate and give the IPA to them. They will then have to codesign the IPA file with their in-house distribution certificate in order to deploy.

The command is
`codesign -f -s {SIGNER-IDENTITY} "/Path for your .app file"`

where `{SIGNER IDENTITY}` is iPhone Distribution: Company, Inc. which they can find in keychain access and  `Path for your .app file` is in your payload folder.  Unzip your ipa and payload folder you will find yourapp.app  so it would look like this

`codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Company, Inc." /Users/MyName/Desktop/MyApp/Payload/MyApp.app`

Comment: Please add some punctuation -- it's very difficult to read past the third line in that seven-line run-on sentence.