# Debugging on device without apple developer account (iSDK 5 and XCode 4)

Tags: debugging, xcode4, ios5, jailbreak

So, my question is very short: is it possible to debug my application on actual device without Apple Developer account ? I am using SDK for iOS5, XCode 4.2 and Snow Leopard 10.6.7.

I know that it is possible with older versions of XCode and SDK, but don't remember how (I found it on the net some time ago ...)

EDIT: I have jail-broken iPhone and have no problem if solution needs jailbreak ;)

Comment: Did you get this working with Xcode 4.2?

Comment: So did you downgrade Xcode to get it working?

Comment: @newenglander: No, I'm just not debugging on a device.

Comment: Hey I just got it working, Xcode 4.3 on Lion for iOS 5. See [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34802/8699) (jailcoder)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11171/discussion-between-newenglander-and-xx77abs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working (on-device debugging using Xcode 4.3/Lion/iOS 5) using an app called Jailcoder, which I discovered in this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34802/8699). It sets up Xcode and indvidual project files and can apparently revert the changes (haven't tried this though).

Update: Works for me only in safe mode on the iOS device, otherwise not.

Update2: Not working for me in safe mode either now. But this is still worth a try, especially as it's free.

Comment: The post is gone, here's a link to the page for Jailcoder: http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing for a jailbroken phone- yes you can. As Bill indicated, it's not possible otherwise. On a jailbroken phone, you can get logs from /var/log/syslog. You could also enable debugging of a self-signed app with Xcode. Details of enabling that is discussed in [iPhone App Minus App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store). It seems to only work on older versions of XCode. I was not able to get these procedures working on XCode 4.2/ iOS5- so let us know if you do!

Answer (score 1):

The short simple answer is no. To test on a device, you need a provisioning profile installed with your device information that you can only generate with a paid developer account.

I noticed you have the jailbreak tag so I'm assuming you are developing something that will probably never need Apple's blessing, so why bother. I'm sure there are methods out there, but nothing quick and easy. But for this question and anyone reading it down the road, the answer is no.

Comment: ok ... I just thought it would be possible, because it is possible on earlier versions of XCode ;)

Answer (score 1):

[iphonedevwiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Developing_without_Provisioning_Profile) has an article that started around xcode 3 but has an implementation using ldid for xcode 4+. Might want to check that out. I can't say that I've tested it, but that's the solution I'm going to try when I get home today. I'll update with whether or not it worked.

The ldid method was developed by saurik and is the method he uses since he does not write code on a mac so his listed [method 1](http://www.saurik.com/id/8) does not work for him. Since you're still pseudo-signing, I'm going to assume that this *does* require a Jailbroken iOS device to deploy to still.