# Deploy iphone app to factory unlocked iphone

Tags: iphone, deployment, camera

I have an iphone app which has some camera functionality which i want to check if it is working alright. I also have a factory unlocked iphone 3gs. Is there any way of deploying my app to the device without paying the $99 fee.

Comment: factory unlocked ? You mean jailbroken, correct?

Comment: no. its not jail broken.

Comment: fair enough. but I don't think you can compile and sign without a working Apple iOS Dev certificate...

Comment: Is this solution not possible if i jail-break my iphone? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store

Comment: Don't believe it will. It's your compiler that needs the certificate, not your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate an IPA file from source code you will need a valid certificate from Apple.

If you already have the IPA file and by "unlocked" iPhone you mean "jailbroken", then you can load the application in the iPhone using different methods the ones that come to my mind are:

- iPhone Configuration Utility
- Via SSH if you enable SSH functionality in your device.

Comment: i do not have a jail broken phone. it is just factory-unlocked.

Comment: if the device is not jailbroken there is no way you can load your app in it without adding the device to a valid provisioning profile and signing the code using valid Apple certificate.

Comment: ok. then i need to jail-break my iphone, create a certificate, genetate an ipa file and then load the application?

Comment: if you create a certificate, that means you have a valid Apple license and you don't need to jailbreak your iPhone. Therefore in that case you can follow the legal flow of distributing iPhone app. Have a look to this link for more information: http://iwings.net/i_can_fly/how-to-archive-and-build-your-first-iphone-app-for-distribution-using-xcode-4