# Distributing apps for testing by the customer

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have to deliver the current state of the project to the custumer to validate it. My doubt is how to do it. The .app build is the executable file of the project? Is it possible to be executed by the customer on their iPhone?

Many thanks!

Comment: Look into ad-hoc provisioning, or this link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend https://testflightapp.com/. Easy for everyone involved.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard says, Ad-Hoc versions are the way to go.

(and if Richard changes his comment to an answer, I'll upvote that too).

Here is a tutorial that you can refer to:

http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/ad-hoc-distribution-build-for-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

A)have you added the UDID of Client's device to your using Provision Profile..?.

if yes, then you can send ".app" file to your client along with the Provisioning profile.
 Then Installing .app file into Client's device

1) Drop the .app file with the Provision Profile into the Itunes application.

2) Choose the device from right window of itunes.

3) Click Apps

4) Click SynchApps

5) Choose the App(you going to install) and

6) Then After Click On Apply

B)If No,then You need to create Adhoc/Distribution build. 
For creating the Distribution Build You need Distribution Certificate and provision Profile.

[Go through this Link for creating the Adhoc/Distribution Build](http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/ad-hoc-distribution-build-for-iphone/)
then you may send the Build to your Client.

I hope it'll help you.