# iPhone SDK: System() questions

Tags: ios, system, nslog

I got bored earlier and wondered if you could execute terminal commands on the iOS platform. Surely enough, just like OSX you can. This is really awesome, but how do I output what the terminal outputs to a text area or something similar? It's nothing serious, just a fun project.

I am using system("") to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, my friend is one of the downsides to using `system`. I also hope you understand that `system` is unavailable on a non-jailbroken iDevice, so unless you are installing it as instructed on the #1 answer on [iPhone App Minus App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store), then you can't use it.

Now, moving forward, you have a few options.

1. Pipe the output of the command to a file, and read that file in your application. Your code should look something like this:

   ```
   system("myCommand -f \"/path/to/my/file\" > output.txt")

   NSString *results = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"output.txt" usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
   NSLog(@"%@", results);
   ```
2. Create the process with the `popen` function, and then pipe the output directly into your application:

   ```
   NSFileHandle *openProcessRead(const char *command)
   {
       FILE *fPtr = popen(command, "r");

       NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fileno(fPtr) closeOnDealloc:YES];

       return fileHandle;
   }
   ```

   You can now use the [NSFileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilehandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs to do what you need.

Comment: Shame about its jailbroken exclusivity. But I just need something simple for me to use. Great answer! Thanks for the helpful advice! :)