# Is there ANY POSSIBILITY of testing an iPhone-App without jailbreak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to test a self-created app on my iPhone without buying an Xcode Developer Acoount.
I've searched everywhere but found nothing that works. I won't pay 79€ for an acc. only to test my App.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone App Minus App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store)

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is learn Objective-C and Cocoa you can test your apps on the simulator. But if you want to actually test on a real device, which is important if you're actually shipping an app in the app store, then you have no choice but to join the developer program.

Comment: +1 the simulator is extremely underrated. I do at least 90% of my development on the simulator. Certain things are hard-to-impossible to test -- like multitouch gestures -- but in general the simulator is a great way to learn objective-c for iOS. As you mention, if you're shipping an app you have to test on a device, because there are occasional and random differences.

Comment: Yes, I know ... i can use the simulator but I want to test my graphics on a real retina display... so the simulator is not enough...

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way. You have to pay the $99 fee to test your apps on a real device. Or you can jailbreak your phone. But without jailbreaking or paying the fee, no, it's not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There are distribution programs that do not require a jailbreak, however these tend to be for use by companies internally and as such probably don't save you any money. Perhaps you could find a trial version.

As a side note, if you are running iOS 5, the [absinthe jailbreak](http://greenpois0n.com/) is incredibly stable and 'safe'.

Comment: safe in that you can come back from it?

Comment: You can, just make sure to generate ssh blobs before you jailbreak

Answer (score 1):

Technically, what @DrummerB said isn't entirely true. If you could find a willing, licensed iPhone developer who would put you on their development team, you could operate using their provisioning profiles and certificates until you pay to upgrade.

I just want to point out however, that this is not something that I would personally do for you, you should just buy the certs for $99 yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a student, you could look into the [Apple Developer University Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/university/). This program is free for students, and will allow you to test your app on real devices. However, with this membership level you will NOT be able to submit apps to the App Store. You will still need a paid membership for that.

Comment: But the Apple Developer University Program is only for Universities and not for a single student. My "school" have to register their not me...

Comment: @DavidBrüggen Sorry about that, I guess I was mistaken!