# Can we deploy an app on iPhone without having paid account

Tags: ios, deployment

Just a simple question. Can we deploy application to iOS device (iPhone) without having a paid account.

If yes, can some please describe the steps.

Comment: out IOS device means ? on iTunes ?

Comment: If you're trying to deploy a non signed application, I think that question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not, unless you are deploying for jailbroke devices.

Without a paid account you can not even test/run app on devices.