# Can i install my own app on my iphone without submit to apple store for review?

Tags: ios, iphone

Just want to know if i can install my own app or game on my iphone without submit for apple store for their to review?

Thanks
Hao

Comment: Sure! You can do it via Xcode with or without Developer certificate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone App Minus App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, if you have a developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can install your app on your iPhone without submit app on app store.

You have to go to preference in xCode and than go to account setting and in that add new account and than add your apple Id and password. After that your your account will appear in that list. Than go to project -> general settings and in that select the team with your id and run it on your phone.

But this app will be in your phone for next 7 days only. After that you have to install it again.

Hope this information will solve your problem.